# What is the new upcoming feedback mechanism?

Tags: support, blog

In the newest blog post [We’re Rewarding the Question Askers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers) in the final paragraph, Sara mentioned:

> These changes—increasing reputation points for question upvotes and the improved question asking experience—**along with some new feedback mechanisms we will be announcing next week** are an exciting start to working hand in hand with the community to build a better Stack Overflow.

(emphasis mine)

What sort of changes should we expect?

Will feedback be taken from the community regarding these changes prior to them going into effect?

Comment: I'm not sure what answer you expect here except "Wait a week." If they wanted to announce them before then, they would've said so, no? It's like if a gaming company said "We'll be announcing our new game next week!" and you posted on their forums "What's the game they're announcing next week?"

Comment: Obviously SE are going to first consult openly here on Meta, don't worry, they won't force it top down. Chill.

Comment: @scohe001 the answer I'm hoping for will explain the sort of changes we'll expect as my question asks. Also, take a look at my reply [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338140/what-are-the-new-upcoming-feedback-mechanism#comment1125623_338141).

Comment: @Script, the new feedback mechanism will be Microsoft Teams and Meta will be discontinued. Happy? ;)

Comment: Might be a cryptic reference to [the new Close Vote initiative](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390083/threshold-experiment-results-closing-editing-and-reopening-all-become-more-eff)

Comment: Announcing that you're going to announce something is terrible practice imo, but all too common unfortunately...

Comment: This question is NOT primarily option-based, I'm expecting an official answer thereby making it NOT opinionated.

Comment: @gdoron is supporting Monica: Not all may get the sarcasm (though easier than [TechLead's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODaq-JEiIKg)).

Answer (score 9):

Erm... they say the changes are going to be announced next week. If a question by a user on meta were to be productive, you'd need their article to say something like "these changes will be announced as soon as you ask us about them on meta!" which is like them astroturfing for their own platform, which is as silly a thing to do as it seems.

They will post something when they're ready to post it and release it. Your question as it stands is completely unhelpful because you know that they have said that they will release the changes next week.

Comment: I'd very much disagree with this. Previously when they've left hints to upcoming changes and a user has prompted for information, they've either given more information or they'll say we can''t. Either answer will work here, I'm just trying to gauge how open these changes will be based on the response or lack thereof.

Comment: @Script47: Are you expecting an answer from corporate?  They've pretty much stopped meaningfully interacting here.

Comment: @Script47 So you want them to say "Read the section you quoted. It says that we'll reveal the changes next week."? Doesn't seem like a great question in that case.

Comment: @Orkin sure, I'd be fine with them saying that. If you don't agree with the question, that's fine.

Comment: This is starting to look like a sign that people will just ask billions of questions about hyped topics which have trivial answers, which may or may not be related to the fact that a single upvote now gives everyone 10 sizzling spicy reputation points.

Comment: @Orkin well, if that's a side effect to the rep changes then I guess that's something that should've been considered on their end. But, as far as this question goes, that thought hadn't come into my mind. I'm merely interested in what I've stated in the OP.

Comment: @MarkKirby Not strange at all. There are people who may be (perhaps legitimately, perhaps just paranoia) concerned that if they ask a touchy (yet arguably reasonable) question in Meta that it might be used against them in some fashion elsewhere in the network. An unfortunate side effect of the current state of affairs.

Comment: That makes sense, I guess I just didn't think of that and overthought it, thanks for explaining, I removed my other comment.

Comment: @MarkKirby No problem; it's a fair question.