# The "loop" has arrived. What does the community think about it?

Tags: discussion, blog, the-loop

According to [plan](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338860/what-about-that-new-feedback-mechanism), SE Inc. has released a lengthy blog post about ["the loop"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/), and their vision of a new "community feedback" system. Or something:

> TLDR; We’re going to be sharing our product development process with you, from feedback loops to timelines. We’ll be doing so through our new series – The Loop. You can give us your thoughts on what you’d like to see us do by filling out this survey: Through the Loop. We’ll also be releasing Moderator Training and some new feedback mechanisms to help us form decisions as we grow.

What does the community think?

And in case you want more specific "boundaries" for your answer:

- Do you see that "the loop" can work and lead us to a "place" that works for "us" community?
- If so, how does your vision "on top" of "the loop" look like?
- If not, what are your main objections?

---

<sub>I understand that this question is pretty broad, but honestly: the topic itself is pretty "broad", and I do think: broad discussions are going to happen anyway. So why not "bundle" that stuff in one place. And as soon as more distinct topics arise, those will surely be addressed in distinct questions.</sub>

Comment: Well, we can all answer the survey with how we are troubled by the way Monica Cellio was treated, as well as by other SE decisions. Maybe they'll listen this time.

Comment: Are you interested in anything specifically? This is not a broad discussion forum, so a bit of direction seems necessary if you want more than a large, incoherent collection of opinions.

Comment: "We’ll ... create a new working group of users that we’ll lean on for regular feedback" ... "By the end of this year, we will have completed discovery for the working group of users and will have identified the people we would like to recruit.". The user working group is selected by SO employees, not nominated by/voted for by the community. It's also not clear what sort of process there will be for choosing the members of the moderator advisory team, or how much input mods/users will have when a team member is replaced. So... I'm not optimistic.

Comment: @AJM-Reinstate-Monica spoiler alert: "advisory group" will be a cherry-picked set of employees most loyal to the king and nobody else, with the subtext that if you're not part of the group it's because we want to sack you in a year.

Comment: @AJM-Reinstate-Monica I can undrestand SE employees vetting that core group. However, there aren't even public *applications*. I'm not even sure how they're even trying to *find* that "diverse" group of users, given that they apparently want them assembled in about a month.

Comment: **people from all corners of the developer community** Stack Overflow and programmers are apparently the only thing that matters even though there are 100+ non-developer communities. Typical.

Comment: @ColleenV they may be taking that a bit broadly. ;p On ELL users develop their 2nd/3rd/4th.. language. On ELU users develop complex grammatical structures. On Skeptics users develop their critical mindset. On Area51 users develop new communities. And on this Meta people complain about mismanagement.

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica on CGCC we develop code and focus on making it as unreadable as possible :D

Comment: I am completely lost. Look again at the infamous survey question #5 about *which racial background(s) you identify with*. Doesn't it look a little short? I mean, if you're going for racism, why leave black people out?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I couldn’t believe it. Normally it’s Asians that get screwed over in American race politics, but to leave black people out entirely? Wow.

Comment: @ColleenV Yes. Note that the whole "loop" only asks about StackOverflow.

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica Actually there’s a required question about how long you’ve been coding... no option for the non-coders because their opinion doesn’t count. And for the record I’ve been coding for *cough* 3 decades.( I uh, started when I was uh 2 ;)) so I am fluent in “developer”. Reading between the lines I still get “People who don’t know the difference between managed and unmanaged memory don’t have relevant opinions about the important work developers do” (paraphrasing).

Comment: It's weird to me that they state that the "current Code of Conduct" was published in 2018 and link back to the 2018 blog post announcement rather than the ACTUAL current CoC announcement which was, what, a month ago? It could be a simple editing mistake, but it needs to be corrected either way.

Comment: They apparently want to cut us out of the loop.

Comment: @Giuseppe Rather they're just going with the flow of their previously employed narrative of the CoC always being the way it is now and just requiring a "minor clarification" about what a specific phrase from it means in specific situations.

Comment: The whole thing reads as satire, really...couldn't take it seriously at all

Comment: Hey All - thanks for the feedback here we're reading through all of it. The demographic questions should not have been mandatory, the survey has been updated. Appreciate you pointing that out.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi It's kind of unbelievable...this is so wrong

Comment: @SaraChipps Err, I don't care whether it is mandatory or optional. It is plain wrong, doesn't belong in any survey written in 2019. Yet, kudos for showing up here.

Comment: My last statement for today: given that SE Inc supposedly invested plenty of time and preparation, and actually moved out this announcement a few days ... I am wondering how terrible and bad the *initial* material must have looked. Un-f....ing-believable.

Comment: @SaraChipps can you explain why it uses the same language used by [many hate groups](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/latino/opinion-white-nationalists-are-wrong-european-does-not-mean-white-n694831)? (beyond the complete lack of options which is further horrible)

Comment: @SaraChipps Interesting that your demographics questions ask about "race", and do not ask about nationality. Do you assume all users are from the US? If you don't want the question to be offensive, and yet want the statistics for some reason, why not ask about nationality/ethnicity, and leave the thing open, rather than multiple choice?

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica kudos for showing up? Sara has shown up several times in recent controversial posts and assured us that feedback is being taken into account and we've either been ignored or blindsided by changes like these repeatedly.

Comment: @LinkBerest Oh yes, definitely that! I was born in Europe, I could not pass for "white" if I wanted to, and I'd in fact been persecuted out of the place where I was born because my nose was the wrong shape (a.k.a I wasn't the right ethnicity). Last time anyone called my people a "race" was right before packing us off to Auschwitz, so I'm kind of touchy about using that word at all.

Comment: @Script47 and then, after leaving a comment, doesn't appear again...

Comment: @GalastelsupportsGoFundMonica yes, my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica This mess is created by sheer incompetence and a childish view of the world, what else can it be?

Comment: **Update:** the divisive question #5 is now less limited in possible options, which fixes it... in a way. inb4 nln, I'll leave my previous comment here for context.

Comment: In their hurry to fix the poorly-wrought "racial background" question, they managed to misspell *descent*: "Black or of African decent"

Comment: Sounds strange to me, at least at first. Is this some kind of beta testing? I don't want to be part of it. Where is the community in all of it? Difficult to see. So far, rejected. But I'm willing to give it the benefit of the doubt, final judgement delayed until it is working for some time.

Comment: The CEO thinks it's great: https://twitter.com/pchandrasekar/status/1199042453451542539?s=20

Comment: @ReinstateMonica-M.Schröder, yeah, *proactively listen and establish deep feedback loops with our Stack Overflow community.* Nice touch (but not *too* deep, please). You can tell the guy is serious, he has joined Twitter in 2009. I would also like to direct you to [these proactive listening techniques](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/proactive-listening-techniques-42757.html). Sounds great on paper.

Comment: @SaraChipps, since you're here, would you mind answering this question about whether you still intend to respond to the community's open letters, or if this is intended to replace that response? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/338313/is-stack-exchange-still-planning-to-respond-to-the-communitys-open-letters

Comment: Could you cross post this to Meta Stack Overflow seeing as it seems they're the only community the survey is actually intended for?

Comment: @SaraChipps Why are the demographic questions even in there? How are you planning to use the data?

Comment: This isn't diversity. It's the US interpretation of diversity. Big difference.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica-M.Schröder _"The CEO thinks it's great"_ Ah, dammit. Well, there goes another bit of hope.

Comment: @SaraChipps Why does the survey not ask about our religious affiliation? Surely if there's one aspect of people's identity that is likely to cause them to be discriminated, it is religion? Does SE not care about under-represented religious minorities? How could you have missed this opportunity to put us into an additional box?

Comment: "Meta requests don’t integrate with any existing ticketing system." That perfectly explains why Monica hasn't been reinstated. No one's opened a ticket for it.

Comment: Because "gender non-binary" is definitely the standard term. /s Honestly, was any proofreading done at all?

Comment: In Europe, this kind of race question would be flat-out called for what it is: discriminative. You *don't* need that information; requiring it (or allowing to optionally put it in) is at best noise in the data, at worst a way to filter behind the scenes.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I let him know what I think about his idea ....

Comment: The name and the idea of having a selected group of followers instead of the whole community somehow feels like a cultural cliché taken from a dystopian sci-fi movie of the 80s. Are you not in The Loop? Be in The Loop! The somewhat immersion breaking thing is that they also kind of botched the roll-out.

Comment: I'm satisfied with the speed of the company rolling out new features lately, I'm just not satisfied with the direction. Unfortunately, the net effect is negative and I have never thought harder about alternatives ever.

Comment: Regarding the demographic questions such as gender, race, age, nationality,etc: how would SE even start to verify that everybody is answering those questions truthfully? And if anybody can pretend to be part of a minority group (e.g. thinking their feedback would be prioritized over others), it's worthless to base anything upon that information, and thus it's useless to collect that information.

Comment: So are they only looking for feedback from Stack Overflow users in particular right now?  It seems like I should only respond to the survey if I use SO (which I don't).  Is this survey being used to affect the entire network, or just SO?  If it's the former, why is the survey only geared towards SO?

Comment: @SébastienRenauld In some places it's illegal to ask for.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Correct. In France, for instance, it is dangerously illegal; same with Germany. Also, on top of that I see no right to view, edit or delete information despite SO/SE (and that survey) being accessible to us Europeans.

Comment: We've already moved on from pretending Monica doesn't exist to pretending majorities don't exist, and now we're pretending nobody at all exists!

Comment: [Joel left, and SE as we know it is dead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339074/191655)

Comment: All the recent talk about "inclusivity" and the first version of this survey excludes "Black / African American".  Oh, the irony. The first impression is one of something hastily thrown together, and poorly thought out. i.e. Not ready for prime time.

Comment: These weekly controversies are becoming quite tiresome.

Comment: So you introduce a focus group ... and eventually close this pesky Meta.

Comment: @Ageax it's fine to exclude 99.7% of the community, cherry-pick a working group that fits your ideals, and keep all the data private so nobody sees that, yeah?

Comment: It's rather telling that they are trying to invent something new while most of the community is programmers from all layers of experience, plenty of which are very familiar with feedback systems. On all identification questions, I answered "Other (Comment: This is irrelevant for StackOverflow - because it should be.)"

Comment: @SébastienRenauld - If the goal is appearances, rather than taking the time to put together an approach which actually addresses the issues of the whole community,then yes ;-)

Comment: Technical definition of racist: one who subscribes to the philosophy that races exist and the global human population can be divided into races. On that basis, quite a lot of US society and culture really is extraordinarily racist. How depressing.

Comment: It looks like a way to move criticism from a page where everyone can discuss it into a more closed section, that prevents the general public from reading and discussing the criticism, thus enabling the team to hear the feedback without any need to react, because everyone thinks "maybe I am the only one with this feedback", while meta allows people to see how many other people share their opinion.

Comment: Y'know, in our country, sometimes we have these "National Consultation" thingies. It's our Loop… https://hungarianspectrum.org/2017/04/02/national-consultation-2017-lets-stop-brussels/

Comment: @SaraChipps please fix the misspelling of “decent” - it should be “descent”. It’s disrespectful to have such an error after they were left off the survey list.

Answer (score 335):

The "loop" is bad news. Here's why.

- **No community engagement**. On Meta, we get to voice a problem, users propose various solutions and weigh them against each other, maybe we get convinced that what we initially thought was a problem is in fact a desirable, or at least unpleasant-but-necessary feature. We work together as a *community* to make this platform we use together better. The "loop" turns it into "Dear SE, will you fix this for me?"
- **No transparency**. If a complaint is voiced on Meta, we see it. We see how much traction it received. With everything hidden, SE can claim that a change was due to "multiple complaints" or alternatively that a problem "is actually very small", and we have no way of seeing whether that's right.
- **No discussion**. Following the above two points, now changes will be landed on us, without us having any opportunity to have any sort of public say in the matter. The King commands, the peasants bow and do what they're told.
- **Race and gender segregation**. All our responses to the loop will be grouped by race and gender, for SE to do with this data as they see fit. (Mind you, in my native language, the word for 'race' is one you'd use to talk of dog breeds, and only apply to humans in historic context, e.g. when speaking of [Scientific racism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_racism). So I find the very question offensive and troubling.)

Comment: I think most users are of the [human race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_Race). If there are users from other [species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Species) then that would definitely be interesting, though it may well be humans trying to pass as animals.

Comment: "No community engagement" what? The first of their three focus groups is "Better Mechanisms for Community Feedback". You might want to reword that bolded text.

Comment: @EmC They've turned what used to be public discussion into some black box where any input that goes in is only seen by those who write it, and may or may not be completely ignored by those running the site

Comment: @EmC IIUC, they'll only be collecting feedback from a cherry-picked group of users, with nobody else even being given the technical means to do so. You get one guess as to what group they'll be cherry-picking from in practice.

Comment: That's not *no* community feedback, that's "I don't like their proposed mechanisms for community feedback". Hence, you might want to reword the bolded text.

Comment: @EmC let me spell it out for you: in all certainty, said advisory council is going to be a subset of their employees. If it's not going to be an empty front entirely. Even including  some moderators would count as a pleasant surprise.

Comment: @JohnDvorak oh I'm well aware of what you meant! If you want to say "I don't trust SE to pick a representative subset of users", just say it, don't couch it in statements that aren't true if you read the blog post as written :)

Comment: @EmC but the answer says "no community **engagement**", which is completely true

Comment: Get with reality - The 'community' has been weighed, measured and found not wanted. Move along now ...

Comment: Is market research done more like this new process, or or more like the old "community" process?

Comment: +1 for the race thingie, same in my language, it's very offensive when translated.

Comment: @JohnDvorak "You get one guess as to what group they'll be cherry-picking from in practice." The non-hostile group? Btw. I love SO and I'm so super excited to see it growing so much.

Comment: Where does it say responses to "the loop" will be segregated by race and gender?  That seems a little... extreme.  Not that I don't think such a crazy thing is possible, where I live, the city government  tried some weird meeting where they had segregated meetings to talk about racism, and segregated school meetings by all the various popular identity categories.

Comment: @SteveSether: There are two options: either the data is supposed to be used for evaluating the survey - which makes your point moot - or it's not there for a reason - which would be even worse: "asking people about likes/dislikes is too short, we need to pad this out!"

Comment: @Piskvor There's almost always more than two options to everything.  Either way, it seems a huge stretch that suddenly everything is going to be segregated by race/sex by taking one survey question and extrapolating.  The problem with this whole story is everyone is massively speculating what "The loop" is, without it having to be applied.  "What you do you think about (thing we know little about)." Is just a poor question in general, and seems to invite creating fantastical theories without evidence.

Answer (score 252):

The phrase "for reasons they don't understand" is offensive. We do understand why changes out of the blue bothered us, Sara. We listed those changes for you to read. The illegal relicensing, the horrific way you slandered a user to the media, the inappropriate animated advertisements, the abrupt Code Of Conduct changes that didn't take any user input. All of them had reasons listed.

The segregation of data and input by race, gender, and sexuality is offensive.

The idea that we need to be "trained" to deal with those issues when it is them that has to be trained to deal with those issues is offensive. We as a community (users, moderators) are not the ones that led to death threats and data mining of the lavender community. They are.

The condescending wording of the article is about how we're the problem, how we need *training resources* and a *curriculum*, how we need to adapt to create a "welcoming community" and how we "don't understand" why the sudden, abrupt changes upset us.

With this in mind, their "hand selecting" individuals is not an idea that I think is useful, as I'm not sure it will be to further specific agendas and to solidify the idea that Stack Exchange is not accountable, or to actually improve site experience.

Instead of hand selecting individuals to confirm their bias for them, they should categorize the issues they think are important, and allow community feedback through a voting process of some sort. Kind of like how Microsoft did User Voice, to be honest.

Comment: What if she'd said "For reasons I don't understand, la-la-la, covering my eyes and ears, can't hear you!" ? ...

Comment: Yes, if the real problem is that staff members (and some other users as well) are downvoted on meta because of *who they are* and not because of what they *say*, the solution should be to change the software such that voting on meta is only on issues and proposals (dissociated from any particular user), and only after some process with a number of phases (much like moderator elections). It would also be much easier to change the software; people are very, very difficult to change, even if they are initially willing to (it may even backfire).

Comment: I'm a little confused about the "reasons we don't understand" thing. The blogpost reads: *Long-time users can be surprised by things changing out of the blue for reasons they don’t understand,* I understand that to mean that things are changing for reasons they don't understand, and that surprises them. It sounds like you are reading it as saying that they don't understand why they are surprised. Am I missing something?

Comment: I will say that we moderators have been asking for training on many issues for *years*, this is actually something we really want. At least for some topics specifically. I definitely don't see that part as talking down or being insulting.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica I received a warning from moderators recently for talking bad about staff (and I don't even think I took it as far as you). I know you said you don't care: but just lettin ya know. Half of me wants to write a blog post about how wrong it was, half just wants to say "screw this site, it's not worth my sanity anymore".

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica When listening to the podcast between Sara, a white feminist, and Kim, a black feminist, it became apparent Sara felt she, as privileged person over black women, did not do enough to protect this group. I think much of her latest actions and policy changes of the company have been heavily influenced by this conversation. I advise you to listen this through, just to get Sara's situation, whether you agree with _identity politics_ or not (https://hashtagcauseascene.com/podcast/sara-chipps/).

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica "This. Sara is one of those people who is so dead set on doing the right thing..." Being dead set on something doesn't have to be a bad thing in general. Sometimes persistence is even seen as a positive trait, depending on the goal probably. But I just wanted to say that singling out a person is the wrong approach here. The CTO backed Sara publicly and the CEO is proud of the new development. She is basically covered and the whole management of the company is in it together. If you want to blame someone, it's better to blame the whole management of the company.

Comment: @Trilarion Oh, I do. I think that's well-documented. & persistence is fine but tunnel-vision is not.

Comment: @Alex That doesn't make it any better. It implies that our judgement is somehow faulty because we simply don't understand their reasons. Both ways of interpreting that statement leads to the same conclusion of being condescending and deflecting responsibility.

Comment: A very astute comment has gone missing from here.

Comment: @Piskvor I noticed those (selective?) variations in voting limits as well. And some 100+ liked comments also disappeared in a couple of recent posts.

Comment: Aaaand my previous comment is gone, too.

Answer (score 180):

For me the key takeaways boil down to:

> Long-time users can be surprised by things changing out of the blue for reasons they don’t understand, ...

No mentioning of *long-time users* worry about quality and community spirit, aka *working hand in hand*, as promised in that [previous blog article](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/). A bit of that shows up later, but I had hoped to see it right there, as that would have shown: "you listened".

> It’s been inspiring to see people from our Community Management team work hand in hand with folks from Engineering, Sales, and Marketing to come up with solutions for our community’s most pressing concerns.

That's funny. When we do "Design Thinking" in my place (and I kinda consider my company to be a global thought leader here), one of the first things we learn is: without your end users in the process, there is no point in starting. Without regarding the existing community as stakeholders that *somehow* participate in all such efforts, these efforts are **futile**.

At least: you understand that you need those people, and think about ways to get their feedback. But obviously: you didn't want them around when you *started* your activities. Big mistake.

> We’re going to create a new system to offer training for our moderators.

About time. But yes: go for it, write down rules and practices. That also include **your** obligations and commitments towards the moderators! And having a board also *can* help. How good or bad that will work out very much depends on the subtle implementation details.

Overall: at least a clear vision, presented with the right level of initial details. **But that doesn't mean I find it convincing, or especially appealing.**

> if our users are best served by keeping the function on Meta or if our users are best served by moving the functions to other tools and processes.

My current gut feeling is: if you decide to move the functions to other tools, in other words: in case you close the META(s), I am out. For good.

---

---

To separate concerns: when I saw the announcement, and read "the loop", I *assumed* something like [this](https://www.ibm.com/design/thinking/page/framework/loop):

[image: screenshot the loop]

I then clicked that link, and ended up with a simply survey, containing:

[image: loop-racist-crap]

The only times in my life when I have to answer such a question, that is when writing up a visa for the United States. In any other place, I find such a question to be deeply inappropriate.

We then learned "sorry, the first version of the survey ways broken", which only adds to the impression of SE Inc. not knowing what they are doing. Not regarding "preparation", and this time: also not regarding execution. Seriously: abysmal unprofessional.

The idea:

> plan how to move forward on sensitive issues involving race, gender, and sexuality.

to draw whatever conclusions from that.

And there I agree with the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339136/285661) from Sextus: **every** time I have to look at such kind of surveys (and I see plenty of them, working in a large US based company) I know exactly that *US* management goes totally bonkers about such numbers. Metrics, simple numbers, and a fixation on tools, processes, rules, instead of listening to users. Thus I am really disappointed that a young striving company like SE Inc. starts to act more and more like a 100K-employees Behemoth with a higher management level that is decoupled from the needs of employees and users.

And as written: that *race* part alone got me, and many other folks furious for no reason. Again. SE staff member [Yaakov](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/51/yaakov-ellis) suggests that SE Inc. is reading what happens here. Err, sorry: we repeatedly suggested to you: stop digging the hole you put yourself into. That survey, the survey content, the survey execution was the exact opposite.

And **if you had bothered to ask here before doing that** we could have told you. Before making another big announcement that added another barrel of fuel to the fire.

And yes, today is **Other** day.

Comment: `if you decide to move the functions to other tools, in other words: in case you close the META(s), I am out` They will never actually *close* the Metas officially. Way too messy. They will just leave them there to rot, unread and haunted by the same small group of people who still think SO can somehow become again what it used to be. The time to walk away has long come.

Comment: @Pekka Isn't that already happening?

Comment: @Ghost, I'm proud to be an Other, since we all are. Let's celebrate Other day tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning that part of the survey. Not only is it disgusting for the sheer lack of diversity. When did the people of the Iberian become "white"? Seriously, I see this "European race" (Europe is not a race) kind of **strong word here** in the speeches and arguments of hate groups that come after me

Comment: Interestingly the ethnic background list has grown significantly in the last half hour.

Comment: They've updated that question with more choices and a text field, and marked it optional: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGbBs.png

Comment: Rather than making realtime changes to the survey with every piece of meta feedback that shows they didn't think this survey through, they should take it down, think it through and then activate it again.

Comment: @dfhwze, it's nice they fixed it in the first place (although I wonder who made that blunder and what will happen to them), but that indeed invalidates previous results -- they should cancel and reboot the survey, so to speak. Or maybe it is just for show, who knows?

Comment: Sorry about this one folks. The original list of options that was shown on the survey for this question was supposed to have been switched to the updated list before the survey went live. Our bad on that one. And the same for those questions not being optional. Thanks for bringing it to our attention so quickly.

Comment: But talking with your users using this new Loop thing is still talking with your users, though. Just in a different way from previously. With the potential to be be more systematic?

Comment: I think the "end users" have been included in the process, and I think we're not it.  The users who want a community are being left on the side of the road.

Comment: A large part of Latin people are also of European descent; and arguably White. Also, if you're from the middle of Asia, you're apparently not worthy of your own racial category. Actually, WTF is "South Asia"? That's India and Sri Lanka, right? What a ridiculous categorization.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Why do you even include the demographic questions? What will you use the data for?

Comment: "Updated list"? There should never have been this list in the first place. What forward-thinking person would come up with it to begin with?? I get that groups of people sometimes lag behind the modern wisdom, but if you're going to be so condescending about all this stuff then _at least_ get it right yourselves. For goodness's sake.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica for better or worse, in the US we get asked about race on practically everything.  It's so common they I don't even think about it. It's incredibly interesting to see non US reactions to this.

Comment: @JL2210 answering as a dev, not a data scientist: we use the demographic data to see if there are any specific demographic groups where trends appear regarding site satisfaction and overall likes and dislikes. Helps to answer questions like: do only new users (to the site or to the profession) feel unwelcome, or is it felt across other demographics as well. And lots more along those lines. Also, tracking these trends over time can help to see if user attitudes are changing, and if so, how.

Comment: @YaakovEllis But how is that really "demographic" data? What do you expect, say a German to answer who lives since 30 years in India? Or a German citizens who's grandfather came from a colony in Africa?! And note: the fact that you got the "first" version so terribly wrong ... taking these things together, sorry: this smells deeply unprofessional. I would accept that from a group of students from some small community college trying to come up with their first survey. You supposedly want to address a global community of experts. Sorry: most epic fail I ever saw here (besides Monicagate).

Comment: @Rubiksmoose FWIW here from germany, asking that would likely be illegal or at least seen as unethical and disgusting. I can't imagine a company here doing that, it would be pure PR suicide. People are plenty cautious and sensitive about the last time companies and the government wanted to know people's race.

Comment: @Rubiksmoose I was once told by a friend (who is also a well-known US actor) that "the US is a world leading in this process", where "this process" means improved race relations and equal opportunities. He couldn't understand why I was laughing, and then couldn't understand why I was cross when he berated my country for allegedly being fifty years behind his (he got that backwards). Meanwhile, as if to prove my point, he spends most days criticising the state of race relations in the US. Just completely obsessed, y'all, honestly!

Comment: @rounin and I think people from Huddersfield are weird.

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica The question is asked a lot in the US because the answer affects a lot of other things (at least in the US). If you are a black person born in Germany (for example) and you move to the US, you are likely to experience a very different life, culture, and upbringing than if you are a white person who was born in Germany (or Asian, or Pacific Islander, etc). Maybe other countries are way better about racial discrimination (I really doubt it, though) so they don't have or see the need for such data, but in the US it's just a data point.

Comment: @all re: race being so taboo in Germany, specifically, that is not super surprising, as Germany has a well-known history with this in the Nazis & WWII. Germans are prohibited from doing a number of things that are more or less innocuous everywhere else because those things actually happened in Germany 90 years ago. Though I agree it's more proper to ask for "ethnic background" or something similar instead of race these days even in the US -- we are all Homo (arguably sapiens) AFAIK.

Comment: @Yaakov Ellis I have seen the list of race options being updated at least two times. This was not a question of publishing the wrong list, rather than publishing an incomplete list that the quickly got updated as criticism rolled in.

Comment: *"Maybe other countries are way better about racial discrimination (I really doubt it, though)"* Your feelings of national superiority on this subject are completely unfounded.

Answer (score 143):

I find it disgusting that this survey asks about race, age, and gender, **and offers no option for "prefer not to say."**

In other words, if you want to submit feedback to Stack Exchange, you MUST tell them your age, gender, and race, or you are not able to give feedback at all.  Or, of course, you must lie about your race, age, and gender.  Which may bias the interpretation of your answers anyway.

---

As for the overall shift away from Meta: I might like it better if I still had any trust left for the company.

I don't think there's anything *inherently* wrong with using different feedback mechanisms.  I just don't trust SE to actually act on our feedback.  On Meta, we can at least see how they are responding or failing to respond, and they can't hypocritically pretend they care without the hypocrisy being evident.

Comment: I used "Other" and stated "None of your concerns"

Comment: @dfhwze, I did similarly, but there is no such option for age.

Comment: Pick the option that is most likely to get your feedback used.

Comment: @dfhwze Oh man, you were polite.

Comment: I just took that survey and race, age and gender were optional, so I ignored race and age and replied "This is non of your business" for the gender question, where I could free-form it.

Comment: @wha7ever they [changed the survey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339050/the-loop-has-arrived-what-does-the-community-think-about-it#comment1130678_339050) after feedback here. It wasn't "supposed" to be mandatory

Comment: Which adds even more to the impression of utter *incompetence*. You get your questions perfect **before** you publish them. Because when you change them during the process, you render all initial answers (more or less) useless.

Comment: So, we still needed to use meta for feedback...

Comment: The survey as originally launched had these questions as required. This was a mistake. They have been switched to be optional.

Comment: Nothing is stopping this 85 year old Middle Eastern person of unspecified gender from voting in the survey. Outlier data will either be individually investigated or ignored. Either way it will only be used if it serves in the best interests of The Company.

Comment: If the company had been trustworthy, it would not have stopped answering on Meta.

Comment: @GhostCat says Reinstate Monica: Re *"you render all initial answers (more or less) useless"*: No, there are still the two qualitative feedback free form fields, and they will probably influence the decision making process more than anything else (like 1-1 interviews most likely do). It is far from all numbers.

Comment: @YaakovEllis How did such a mistake slip through? I thought SE had been working on this whole thing for a while? Do you have a Quality department?

Comment: @mason It slips through due to us being busy people (with very good intentions), and due to a lack of clear process for these types of releases (hard to unit test a blog post & survey the same way that you might test some code). One group of people reviewed the survey & added instructions to change the demographic groups. Other(s) were responsible for changing the survey. Other(s) for releasing the blog post. And in the middle of all of this we had a company-wide meetup. You saw the result. We are trying to learn from this and to add a process to catch these types of things for the future.

Comment: @Drew "either way it will only be used if it serves in the best interest of The Company" - I was the dev who added the Satisfaction Survey to the site a few months ago and have seen closely how we look at the similar survey results there (questions very similar to this survey). I have to disagree with your assessment. We look at all responses. Everything gets coded. We pay attention to the things that people want to see improved. There is no "narrative" that we try to support through selecting only some results. The only results that are discarded are cases of obvious trolling.

Comment: @PeterMortensen "there are still the two qualitative feedback free form fields, and they will probably influence the decision making process more than anything else". This. Exactly this. Even without the demographics information, honest feedback in these fields can be extremely impactful.

Comment: @PeterMortensen But that is not how surveys work. What if the *abysmal* first version of the survey got people to stop taking the survey and turn away and disgust? The problem is that nobody can say how that change to the survey questions affects the results.

Comment: @YaakovEllis Hint: if you seek honest feedback ... take two days of, and read through the last 2 months of questions and answers here on MSE. You will see more constructive creative ideas about "what to do better" and "what to do stop doing" there as you will find in your anonymous survey with 2-sentences random text snippets.

Comment: @GhostCatsaysReinstateMonica we read everything on meta and appreciate the constructive ideas that are given here. In addition to this, we are looking to receive feedback from a larger representation of overall site users, including those users who may be engaged on the site to different degrees but do not participate in meta. And you would be surprised at the amount of useful information you can get from two questions like this. Thanks for your feedback and participation!

Comment: @YaakovEllis If so, you do a really good job of hiding that.

Comment: @YaakovEllis You (plural) read everything on Meta? How do you avoid the "[panic attacks and nightmares](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387633/773737)"?

Comment: @YaakovEllis typical "mmk well that's an idea, let's hear from this otherwise silent person because they _must_ have something to say" mentality. Stop ignoring users on Meta instead of searching for less thought-out input from people who don't care about the site.

Comment: @YaakovEllis no.

Answer (score 130):

## It isn't solving the actual problem

The actual problem is that you always mess up and then provide us with a solution which we absolutely hate. You didn't fix the HNQ when sites told you that it's a positive feedback loop for clickbait junk, so the solution was to kick a site off when it blew up on Twitter. You weren't careful with making sure your links to CC by SA were to consistent versions, so you re-licensed everything all of a sudden. You found that the community is generally not very nice to LGBT+ folks, so you kicked out a moderator who supports the non-binary community. And now, you find that meta isn't working great, so you say you want to stop taking the community's opinions and will instead only talk to moderators and read our opinions through check-boxes labelled by your team.

The loop seems like it may succeed in identifying problems to a reasonable extent. But that isn't your biggest issue, since meta does that job just fine. Your issue is coming up with solutions, and now you're trying to say that you won't even let the community *try* to help you find those.

Comment: @MonicaCellio A certain not-be-mentioned employee gave a podcast, in which 'being an ally' was singled out as and conceded to be a problem as well. Psychoanalysis (re;reverse: "identify with aggressor'; since it was all power dominant, cultural appropriation) is actually an insightful perspective on this. Screenshot this while it's hot!

Comment: @LаngLаngС it's probably a bad word choice.  There are allies who are radical extremists, and there are allies who are there as part of normal interactions with other human beings, who are willing to say "that's not cool" to others and generally stand up for folks, and stuff like that.  I'm one of the latter, not one of the former.  I didn't adopt the term "ally"; it's what my queer friends have called me.  Apparently there are other senses of the word; good to know.

Comment: You have to leave it to them that they are consistently heading into one direction only. It's not just chance but there seems to be a plan behind it

Comment: I just think about my UAT at work. I get either nitpickers noticing 0.01rem line height differences, which I really don't mind, or I get the "pass" folks who I am pretty sure didn't really test. What you don't get often, or at all, is a big group of passionate people that understand software deeply and can give expert feedback. I would kill for this kind of feedback on a product. It's painful to watch the company pull back from this.

Answer (score 122):

If The Loop is supposed to give any meaningful feedback to the Company, we are doomed.

It is 5 minute survey about Stack Overflow (other communities... who cares... apparently SE does not)

Besides, usual demographic (age, gender, years in programming) there are two free style edits: what do you like and what you don't like about SO.

Seriously, how will anyone gather and analyze any kind of feedback from that... I have no idea.

Real feedback would be listing all planned changes and asking us what we think about them. It seems that seeking community feedback is just pretense and The Loop is not even trying to hide that.

Comment: I started to answer the survey. I stopped short of submitting it when I realized that after the demographic questions, the next button was "done".

Comment: @hazzey I was a bit woozy so I played along... but yes, even in those "usual" questions there is a lot to object to.

Comment: And let's not forget that this surveymonkey survey, which is merely a "what you like" box, a "what you don't like" box and then a series of demographic questions so bad they had invalidate the results changing the questions after launch because they literally forgot black people exist (!!!), is [what they came up with after delaying launch by a week because it "needed some refinement"!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338864/178621) What was the unrefined version like?!

Comment: I can't comprehend how they could possibly have forgotten to include black people, especially after that emotional podcast with Kim Crayton about the marginalization of black women in particular.

Comment: @dfhwze Wow, I just realized that. That is horrible omission. I myself didn't pay too much attention... brain cloud... so I just stopped at first checkbox which applies to me and I didn't read further.

Comment: Who is this "us" you are expecting them to ask? The tiny number of MSE regulars? I recognize your avatar, perhaps you recognize mine. That shows just what a tiny group we constitute. A more systematic approach, which sadly means cutting out us MSE regulars, *could* be better.

Comment: @Raedwald Problem is that wast majority of other users don't care. Those 100K new users SO has each month. They just want their answers. Or some just want fake Internet points. Only tiny percentage of those will turn out to be contributing members that will post valuable content. Yes, Meta(s) users only are not fully representative, so surveys do have their place, but then when you have results you take them to the Meta(s) you pinpoint issues and you try to find solutions together with most active users. Ones that keep the sites clean.

Comment: Saying that Meta only has fraction of users and then replacing that input with 1:1 interviews, surveys which will ask wrong questions or focus on irrelevant issues and contextual research that will pull information out of thin air will solve that problem how exactly?

Comment: @Raedwald I am sorry if I sound a bit offensive... I am in a bad mood right now... your questions are valid and I actually agree that Meta is not good representative of complete community. My main problem is not in desire "to widen the input from community" but the fact that after all what has happened it is just a smoke screen. The desire for communication is a big fat lie, that blog post is full of empty phrases and.... I don't know.... I am nor really coherent at the moment...

Comment: More and more these days I think that we are doomed and that's not just because of SE.

Comment: @anonymous what can be done and what is done can be different things. Having free style parts where you can add anything that concerns you and that was left out (because it is hard to anticipate all possible answers) is good, having only free style input (besides those darn demographics, that will be used against us) is  equivalent of saying "just write whatever you want, we will ignore it anyway"

Comment: @Trilarion That is what worries me the most. Everything is falling apart left and right...

Comment: What I don't like about SO? It's corporate management.

Comment: I wouldn't discount the free form fields. They need not be processed in a statistical manner. The best responses will probably highly influence the decision making. Such qualitative feedback is often of much higher value than the quantitative part and often valued as such. They can be highly influential, and you should use the chance you have now. You can sow a seed now that will later save the whole thing. Your words may cause she who shall not be named wake up one month from now in the middle of night and exclaim *"Ah, that is what they meant. I get it."*

Comment: @ResistanceIsFutile I couldn't agree with you more. SE has made it clear to focus on welcoming new users at the expense of the many volunteers that invest their time, expertise and effort to answer/edit questions. The fact many users just create a one-shot account to ask a question for something they immediately need  solved, regardless whether the question has been asked before and unwilling to browsing the help center to adhere to a minimum of quality requirements for asking a question, just doesn't seem to matter.

Answer (score 112):

Some [backchannel diplomacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Track_II_diplomacy) isn't going to work here, even if it's well meaning. We need active dialogue that's open to the community. It lacks [what I've said before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338953/387405) and will say again:

> ## Without discussion, there can be no trust.

There needs to be discussion in the open, for everyone to see and partake in.

Comment: Oh don't worry, they promised that they will have chosen representatives to partake in the discussion on your behalf by the end of the year.

Comment: They don't want our trust. They've apparently decided to circumvent the more active users and stick to shepherding the rest of the users.

Answer (score 96):

## That's not why I elected those moderators

I don't like you giving moderators the updates and asking only the moderators for feedback. I trust my site's moderators with handling flags and keeping discussions and the average undeleted posts' quality up to date. I did not elect them for their role in analyzing and suggesting new features. I want to be part of that. I have ideas. I can see problems in other peoples' ideas. I want to express my opinion about how the community is run, and the moderators I elected were not chosen for proving that they make good feature requests.

Comment: They didn't really say anything about the moderators making the core feedback group, though. They will be users hand-selected by...magic or whatever. But I doubt there will be a lot of moderators among them.

Comment: I think the Answer is referring to comments last week about the "new feedback mechanism" was discussed in Teacher's Lounge (that is, to Moderators Only), and we non-mods were told to just wait until it was Passed Down.

Comment: This is a very important point. If not everyone of the community can be part of improving SE than it's not worth doing it. I don't do all this because of the company.

Answer (score 85):

Meta is a flawed site in many ways. But it does allow for more complex and elaborate discussions and feedback.

The feedback mechanisms I see in the blog post seem to boil down everything into something that fits into a single-line textfield. That doesn't seem all that useful except to get a high-level overview. The mechanisms that allow more feedback than a handful of words are all closed mechanisms like interviews. And even that limits the complexity of the feedback to something you can argue on the spot.

Moving all feedback to channels that can't handle even small amounts of complexity feels like a big step backwards to me.

Comment: US style management, probably learned at Harvard BS. I am working for a large (US based) global player ... and I am used to these kind of nonsense surveys. I am wondering right now whether SE Inc. thinks that by adopting the BS practices that such large enterprise companies used for decades ... they get to "bark with the big dogs".

Comment: I don't think the survey is useless. There are two free-form fields and space for at least 1200 characters, to provide *qualitative* feedback. Instead of providing 1-2 bit of information in the form of an upvote or downvote (*"I am mad at the company, and therefore I downvote"*), there is the chance to get your voice heard.

Comment: I am a machine learning tool and I classified your answer as being frustrated about a barrier to participation. Unfortunately I missed all the other context.

Comment: @Trilarion Ironically that's the only sort of feedback SE wants

Answer (score 82):

Just a few random thoughts.

> We have [..] north of 100k new users signing up to the public Q&A each month (coders are everywhere!)

Indeed they are. So, perhaps using the term "north" to mean "increasing value" is not very welcoming. Are users from the southern hemisphere less valuable? Let's use a term other than "north" to mean "good", because that's a very Americentric/Eurocentric idiom.

> For a community, debt can take many forms: Long-time users can be surprised by things changing out of the blue for reasons they don’t understand,

Let's try to avoid categorising viewpoints from your long-term community members (read: the people who created your monetisable content) as people who "don't understand". Just because somebody doesn't agree with you, doesn't mean that they "don't understand". That's important to, well, understand.

> we have come to the realization that we need to do more in order to sustain, serve and support a much larger community and keep it growing and thriving.

Yes I think that this is a good point.

> We want to address all these things and be transparent about how we’re paying down some of this community debt.

Cool! Paying down debt is awesome.

> A month ago we formed cross-functional teams of Stackers (employees of Stack Overflow)

Ah, my bad; I thought "[Stacker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6244/155739)" was a term meaning [*a user* of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/18/building-community-inclusivity-stack-overflow/). I stand corrected.

> It’s been inspiring to see people from our Community Management team work hand in hand with folks from Engineering, Sales, and Marketing to come up with solutions for our community’s most pressing concerns.

Genuinely, those people are great and they have done and continue to do a fantastic job!

> Over the 10 years that Stack Overflow has been around, the way that we collect user feedback has changed significantly. [..] This shift happened quietly, and many Meta users felt understandably concerned that we weren’t listening to users or making data-driven product decisions.

Yes, you are correct. This came from direct statements that you would not be doing that any more here. That was [directly communicated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387633/560648), thank you.

> We’ll share regular updates about what we learn through our research, as well as create a new working group of users that we’ll lean on for regular feedback. This working group will be made up of a diverse group of folks excited to see Stack Overflow grow.

I am glad that it'll be diverse and exciting.

> Overall, both anonymous and registered users are highly satisfied with Stack Overflow and tell us that their favorite things about our community include finding solutions to their problems, vast access to information, and the knowledgeable people who participate.

I thought everybody hated it, because of the long-term contributors being rude and racist?

I'm glad they've enjoyed the fruits of our freely-provided labour, though. We put a lot into that!

> With our new mixed method research approach, one thing we lost was regular, in-depth conversation with a group of folks highly invested in Stack Overflow’s growth.

Yes, you opted out of that.

> We also wanted to keep seeking out feedback from a broad range of perspectives.

No, you removed (or otherwise made feel unwelcome) the people whose perspectives you did not like.

> We’ll hand-select folks of diverse backgrounds who are excited to chat with us regularly about everything from new ideas to features, to how we communicate with the broader Stack Overflow community.

I am once again glad that diversity and excitement is going to be involved.

> We’re looking forward to hearing from representatives from different types of users and backgrounds starting in 2020 and regularly thereafter.

Cool! Will you be responding to that feedback?

> But wait, there’s more! Moderating communities is a skill, and one that’s too often poorly documented, poorly understood, and pursued without robust best practices.

Again, lambasting your selfless volunteers as lacking understanding is probably not the best way to begin a moderation council, but let's work with it...

> We’re going to create a new system to offer training for our moderators.

Training, or indoctrination?

> The training will be a great way for new moderators to learn the ropes, and will be available to all moderators seeking help as they struggle to make important decisions, learn the tools available to them, and plan how to move forward on sensitive issues involving race, gender, and sexuality.

Alright, that answers that.

As an aside, I actually think it's the directorship that needs a lesson in handling these things with due care and sensitivity, but whatever.

> When conversations about Stack Overflow started to happen on Stack Overflow, our founders invented a site called Meta. Meta Stack Overflow was created as a way to talk about the website without distracting us from the important things: questions about programming. Since then, it’s become almost a catch-all for everything: bug reports, general complaints, feature requests, and ideas about the site. With thousands of accumulated bug reports and feature requests, it’s a lot of community debt.

It actually isn't the debt at all. It's a *sign* of the debt. It's a signal.

Don't shoot the messenger, folks.

You can't fix the deficit by defaulting on your debt then letting it rack up again. But whatever.

> It’s hard to capture structured feedback on Meta. There are now so many conversations that we aren’t often able to participate.

Again, you opted out. You literally said that you were going to do that.

> On Meta, there are discussions, some that go on for a long time without a clear answer.

Like when you illegally relabelled the licence agreement on all our content, then ignored all attempts to communicate with you about it? Yes, I agree.

> Meta tends to exclude people that aren’t super immersed in the Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange culture.

Everybody has access and is welcome. Literally all you have to do is click on a link.

> Meta requests don’t integrate with any existing ticketing system, so our Community Managers need to prioritize the best they can and answer the threads deemed most important at the time.

That's true — a proper issue tracking system would be much better, and I applaud the engineering team for handling Meta-posted bug reports as best they can.

> We analyzed data on how Meta is being used, who is using it, and all the functions that Meta serves. [..] We looked at the three data points—how Meta is being used, who is using Meta, and the functions—and determined if our users are best served by keeping the function on Meta or if our users are best served by moving the functions to other tools and processes.

Okay, this is starting to sound like "let's get rid of the community's most prominent individuals because they have been critical of us; how can we make a new meta-community that excludes them". But, unlike the company, I still assume good faith so let's continue...

> We plan to transition things like bug reports, user and customer support, user feedback, and company announcements off of Meta over the course of next year.

I love this. A+++ would non-Meta again.

> In machine learning, there is a concept called “Human in the Loop.” Some processes can’t just be done by machine alone; instead, a human adds value to the feedback loop.

Yes, we've been doing that for free for over a decade, to generate company revenue. You're welcome!

> Through your help and feedback, we’ll have the best opportunity to build a better future together.

Hope so!

> We’re compiling a small diverse group, including new users, power users, and moderators, to be a constant partner for feedback by Q1 2020.

Good, glad you're taking genitals and skin colour into account because that's an important factor when it comes to people's ability to form ideas.

> This is our initial step, your voice matters here, and we want to hear it.

We have spoken many times. Please respond to the thread about licensing.

> We want to work with you to move past focusing on what’s wrong in order to strengthen the things that are right and build the future we want together.

Yes, we want to move past what's wrong as well.

The way to do that is: **fix what you did wrong**.

This plea to completely ignore all the ways in which you have done **serious, significant and flagrant harm** not just to groups of people but also to individuals, cannot simply be swept under the carpet because you say you want it to be.

You need to take the first steps, and I appreciate the nice words and pleasing promises in this blog post, but until you actually resolve the problems that you've created, it's all meaningless.

> We know that during times of change, communication is important; you’ll be hearing from us the entire way.

Thank you; as such, I look forward to communication regarding the extremely serious issues that have so far not received an acceptable level of interaction from the company.

Let's get this ball rolling and move into 2020 with a renewed sense of co-operation!

Over to you!

---

**tl;dr** ignoring everything, making a system to get rid of us, then asking to move on from "the past" is **offensive** when you haven't fixed what you did wrong.

Comment: What i read from *"We’ll hand-select folks of diverse backgrounds"* is "We'll hand-select a group of people of an equal-ish ratio between experience, race, gender, age, etc, one that importantly *doesn't* represent the community's ratios"

Comment: @KevinB That's right, because apparently it's very important what colour skin you have or what gender you are, in terms of being able to form an opinion or make feedback or contribute. Oh, wait... that's literally racism and sexism! Dammit...

Comment: In terms of *being able to* form an opinion, things like skin color and gender aren't important. In terms of the opinions you *actually do form*, yes, they do seem to be important. They can form the basis for communities, and different communities foster different ideas.

Comment: I like this (Usenet-style) answer very much. The subtle sarcasm is nearly as good [as TechLead's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODaq-JEiIKg) (though there is only one ex-Google ex-Facebook TechLead).

Comment: This is a different meaning of _democracy_ where instead of people of the community being voted in to represent them, people are handpicked using diversity quota to have a demographic representation of all kinds of identity groups. The reason I don't like this is because it focuses on the wrong traits and portrays a moral high ground pushed on others.

Comment: Thanks for the much needed laugh.

Comment: "The way to do that is: fix what you did wrong." Exactly. How the article says it, is like trying to put a plaster on a wound that's infected because they refuse to clean it.

Comment: @laur34-protesting It's like an abusive partner begging you not to leave them, because they mean well and they want you to ignore what they've done. Even though they'll do it again, and practically did it _while asking you_. Why are the virtue signallers so often the ones without virtue?

Comment: [Catija explained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336813/163139) that Sara Chipps used “Stacker”in the first blog
without  understanding of the meaning. Using “Stacker” with clarification (employees of Stack Overflow) shows that now Sara knows the meaning of the word.

Comment: @MiFreidgeim: Oooooor that they're just making it up as they go along and can't make up their minds! ;) The meaning of words is defined by what people mean when they use them. All that aside, thanks for the link it explains a lot :)

Comment: Great read. You captured the irrationality involved in making those decisions into a single sentence. And it made me laugh quite a bit :D

Comment: @MiFreidgeimSO-stopbeingevil Apparently ["Stackers" means users again](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/03/27/stack-overflow-instagram-account/?cb=1)

Answer (score 77):

This is kinda difficult to write. I know there's good folks out there who I actually think believe in meta and the community - and yet, this didn't seem a priority.

It is rather ironic that the new initiative is called "the loop' when for a good chunk of the past year, at least some folks, both in the community and outside it were struggling to break the negative feedback loop between folks in SE and the community.

I've been here a while. I've possibly been active longer than some of your employees. (Though not so long that it was just when you didn’t need moderators, as you had Joel, Jeff, Jarrod, and Geoff, or even Rebecca and Dori and I cannot remember the other one). And yes, SO had three whole CMs at one point. And yes, I once had an argument with Jeff... and kinda had a stalemate. And well, this is kinda what real community is

I do remember though, when folks actually talked. Not at. To. Actual folks (and there's a few folks I feel are genuine and lovely and I trust). It feels like SO has taken to the idea that communicating to people is too hard and would like to stick to nice, neat things like focus groups and surveys. Sometimes, in this mess there's a few hard, but useful truths.

*Community is people*.

The risk with any one source, meta or survey, or even starting with an idea of how either of it is is sometimes we fit the data to try to fit our views. There's a lot of folks who want SE to not just survive, but thrive, and... they're tired.

Do y'all remember you used to use UserVoice? And it *sucked*.  Meta was better... and that's getting replaced by... SurveyMonkey?

I wonder if I've been tilting at windmills - reminding folks that we could be better, and trying to help deal with at least the worst of what was going on here over the past few months.

I've read through the blog-post and I look around. I see many of our most active mods demoralised. There's a site with a single moderator or less. I'm not entirely sure what our moderator community will look like in 2020, a little over a month from now, or what it will look like. I took this role in an *instant*, came back because I had faith in meta as a resource - and, quite honestly, hoped we'd get the help and *good news* we needed to get it back on track. Doesn't feel like this was it.

Many of the older CMs have probably heard of me complaining that the company didn't seem to care about the smaller sites. As a SU moderator - admittedly a pretty drama free site, we've run with a huge amount of autonomy. Reading through the blog post, as someone who isn't a developer, I guess I'm excluded again from the next stage of SO's growth.

I'm not sure what meta means to the company any more.

Or the diverse communities that make up the broader stack exchange network - I had a little faith - stuff was looking up, we had a *few* folks I felt got it - but clearly too few.

Practically, this was not the investment in the community and goodwill I was hoping for.

Answer (score 67):

The loop is anti-transparent.

For a system that considers itself community-moderated, this is a giant step in the direction of removing community discussion on moderation and policy decisions over the whole SE network.

They may as well make the diamond moderators paid positions.  I suspect this is the way things will go in the not-too-distant future, anyway, as if you kill the community feel, there will be little reason to volunteer time.

Edit
So, after trying "the loop", I'm quite underwhelmed.  First, after completing the survey, I can't take it again to make more points.  They only want to hear from me ONCE, apparently.

Many of the questions were of the "nonyabusiness" category, and I answered as such.

There is NO WAY that this can be considered a Meta substitute.  It solicits info on what the staff wants to hear, not on what the staff doesn't want to hear.

I think this is a HUGE step in the wrong direction.  Meta has served the community very well.  Essentially, Meta is the person that brought SE to the dance, and they should leave with that person.  It's brought the platform to a tremendous level.  If the feeling is that Meta hasn't scaled to the platform, the answer isn't to taper off Meta, it's to add mechanisms to get the feedback needed.

I've never been a particularly big meta contributor, but there have been periods of time where I've interacted, and periods of time where I just read.  Until recently, all of the interactions I've seen with staff have been respectful.  There isn't always agreement, but there has always been an acknowledgement that opinions come from someplace.

Lately, I've felt active disdain from staff for users.  I've never perceived that before.

Comment: Na. They *need* to make that a "paid position". After being given money, I'd be quite comfy to say "just following orders…", no matter how…  SE: hire me, –– and pay! I don't mind. I was the advocate of the devil, himself, quite a few times.

Comment: But the survey is better than meta. They have written off meta a long time ago and are not (really) reading meta. At least you have a chance to be heard.

Answer (score 64):

> Software developers often talk about technical debt, the little bugs and shortcuts that you don’t have time to fix, and which over time, can slow, hamper, or completely cripple the system in which they reside. Just like a system can accrue technical debt, as a 10-year-old company, we have accrued community debt.

It appears that Stack Exchange thinks human relationships are like neglected, crappy code that can be fixed whenever you get around to it.

"Hey Valued Users, sure we've insulted you and abused your trust but we promise we'll put fixing the problem with your feelings annoying us into sprints 43-46 next quarter. Also, please self-identify your demographics so we know exactly how valuable you are and can prioritize your concerns appropriately."

Someone seems to have forgotten that they're talking about people, not page views or bug-ridden software.

Comment: This is pretty much consistent to "shipping on Friday" analogy. It is beyond rude and offensive. Developers do have some weird jokes, but even for developers this is not even remotely amusing.

Comment: Also doesn't look to me like the "accrued community debt" is that old, and that the obvious solution to "community debt" is to actually listen to community feedback (which is really easy to do on Meta) and tackle the problems that the community is talking about. But instead, they're adding more to the debt by not treating this issue seriously...

Answer (score 63):

It sounds to me like a thinly veiled attempt to shut down opposition to corporate interests.

Have a problem? Concerned about SE as a corporation? Meh, here's a private survey.  If meta still exists, [which is a huge "if"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339051/will-meta-stack-exchange-be-removed-now), then I have a hunch any type of community issues will be flagged as off-topic, closed or removed.  From Sara stating in the past that employees have panic attacks when posting to meta, to the Monica debacle, to licensing issues, these public conversations *will no longer be able to exist*.

Moderator training = you must do as we say.  Feedback loops = no public discourse.

It sounds like SE doesn't care about the community.  On one hand, I kinda get it - they're a business that needs to make money.  On the other hand, I don't see how removing public discourse will foster a better environment.

Comment: I mean, i'm sure it'l be a "better environment" for someone

Answer (score 52):

The SO blog page [Introducing “The Loop”: A Foundation in Listening](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/) states:

> A month ago we formed cross-functional teams of Stackers (employees of Stack Overflow) to create strategies to start addressing some of these concerns. It’s been inspiring to see people from our Community Management team work hand in hand with folks from Engineering, Sales, and Marketing to come up with solutions for our community’s most pressing concerns. We’ve worked together to build new communication frameworks that take into account how we’ve scaled and to replace old frameworks that don’t work now that we’re larger.
>
> The themes these groups took on are:
>
> - Better mechanisms for community feedback
> - Building a moderator advisory group
> - How we communicate and interact with Meta sites moving forward

I find it troubling that the company seems to be taking *only* a top-down approach to "come up with solutions for our community's most pressing concerns". The blog page says they've worked with different groups within the company, but it doesn't give any indication (and I've not seen any particular evidence either) that they've even asked, much less tried to work with, members of the "community", e.g., most of the people reading this or other more particularly involved members, about what "we" consider to be our biggest problems, as well as how any of their (or, especially, any of our) suggestions about how the company can best solve "our" problems will address these issues.

Another example of their top-down approach is regarding their proposed feedback mechanisms, where the blog page states:

> That’s why we’re creating a working group of users made up of people from all corners of the developer community — from folks new to programming, those who don’t participate in Stack Overflow but are passionate about programming, experienced Stack Overflow users, frequent contributors, and more. We’ll *hand-select* folks of diverse backgrounds who are excited to chat with us regularly about everything from new ideas to features, to how we communicate with the broader Stack Overflow community.

I added the emphasis on "hand-select". Instead of perhaps having an election or some other community-based selection method for determining who "we" believe can best represent & communicate our needs to the company, they will instead choose whoever they want to. No indication is given of what criteria they will use to decide this. Although they may often make good choices, I believe they will likely not choose anybody who decides to question what they're doing too much. An excellent recent example is a certain former moderator who, based on the best information I was able to find, was "fired" just a few months ago for doing this.

Nonetheless, being an optimist, I hope that what they implement will help improve the situation for us, or at least not make things too much worse. Also, where any particular changes are generally detrimental, I hope they will realize this quickly (e.g., through their various surveys or feedback from their "hand-selected" group) and then try to improve the situation. Although what the company wants compared to the diverse (including even sometimes rather contradictory) needs & goals of the "community", especially the generally most active members such as those on this meta site, don't always coincide, I like to believe the company will at least give reasonable consideration to what we're asking to be done, or not be done, before they make their decisions, and then change them afterwards if need be.

Comment: Still trying to figure out how they want to gauge passion or a diverse background from sifting through SO profiles (the only means I can imgagine them selecting candidates).

Comment: Or group results by gender and race from anonymous user profiles for that matter.

Comment: If they wanted meaningful feedback, they wouldn't "hand-select" the working group.  They'd draw names out of a hat until they had enough people who agreed to join the group.

Comment: @Mark That's the kind of suggestion that they would have benefited from if they had bothered to seek input from the community, instead of just dictating to it. But apparently, we aren't worth listening to.

Answer (score 46):

### The Community Is Dead...

This change makes me feel more and more like the community is being pushed out of the loop.

As others have already quoted:

> We’re compiling a small diverse group, including new users, power users, and moderators, to be a constant partner for feedback by Q1 2020.

By this, it feels likely that those who are unwilling to share their gender, race or age with you will not be considered for the role, and that (taking into account recent actions of yours) those who have opposing points of view may be at risk of not being accepted either.

You're shrinking your own feedback loop in an effort to understand our feedback in a more concise manner, but that's what voting on meta is for. That's what your existing moderators are for. You have built a feedback machine, and you're abusing it.

You should not be compiling the group, the community should be (in a moderator election styled event), so that they can vote on the members who have the ideas that resonate the most *with them*.

We're retracting because what we have here is a democracy. Everyone has an equal voice. Everyone has the chance to vote. Everyone has the potential to create real change. Everyone can make a post and make their feedback known, and those in charge (you, The Company) need to take into account those votes and pieces of feedback, and use that information to enact the change that the community needs.

To fix the community, you need to address the problems that we are voting most about. Things like the re-licensing, the moderator firing and subsequent resignations and the community's outcry for more communication from the company in a genuine feedback loop, perhaps by using your own, pre-existing meta.

So what do you say?

### Long Live The Community?

> We plan to transition things like bug reports, user and customer support, user feedback, and company announcements off of Meta over the course of next year.

If this plan goes ahead, I fear you will lose your community, I feel these changes will create an environment where moderators may as well be employed by you. Some people may be passionate enough to contribute, but behind the scenes (in the land of Meta-believe) when the communication between other members of the community has died off, the decay will creep into the other sites, and there won't be a reason for the majority of long-standing users to contribute.

That is, unless you allow us to continue to view others issues and allow us to show our response to your announcements using upvotes (or similar) paired with a publicly written feedback loop involving the community wherein we can remain megaphones for the issues that we (as content creators for the site) find most pressing.

Comment: That option *is* on the survey.  Did they just add it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I'm referring to the screenshot of another answer on this question by [Ghostcat Says Reinstate Monica](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339057/382667), which has the screenshot of the issue there

Comment: Re *"here is a democracy."*: No, dissenting voices and/or those that are not in the ingroup are (effectively) voted out (or silenced) and publicly shamed. That is not a real democracy. Meta becomes insular that way.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That survey got updated (one or more times) after swift user feedback about missing options (for users to opt out of stating their age/gender/race) and adding additional ethnic groups.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, look to the UK and you see dissenting voices from both sides being voted out and publicly shamed. Look to the US and you see a similar situation. This is what democratic systems seem to have become. The issue is that some users will resort to personal attacks rather than the constructive criticism of ideas - but that's where the moderators and staff can jump in. One of their roles is to keep the discussion on topic, and that would involve helping the community shift back onto topic whenever the conversation starts drifting away from that debate of ideas

Comment: I do think transitioning user/customer support and arguably bug reports off of meta is a good thing. User support requests are often harshly received by a community that has dealt with similar things for years, so letting SE handle them probably helps the site be less harsh. Bug tracking on meta is a pain without any integration into their dev system. Hard to know if they saw the bug, are working on the bug, de-prioritized it, fixed it, whatever. A public bug tracker would help. The last two - user feedback and company announcements - are the ones where I think moving off meta will be bad.

Answer (score 44):

> We know that during times of change, communication is important; you’ll be hearing from us the entire way.

So... starting now? This seems to be a large effort to hit a "reset" button and make the last month of Meta disappear.

Comment: "Month"? You're cute. ;-)

Comment: @ChrissaysReinstateMonica I was trying to be a little generous.

Comment: You know... it's interesting that, because communication is _so_ important, they're doing away with a feedback method that allows for communication and  replacing it with a slotted blackbox that whirs gently each time you submit a feedback.

Comment: Is free firm text feedback practical at scale? They are claiming it is not. To make them change their mind,  you would have to prove it can be made practical. The mess that is MSE suggests they are right.

Comment: @Raedwald The survey is entirely free form text.

Comment: Freeform text from a small number of selected users is surely more practical than from an enormous group.

Comment: @Raedwald The survey is linked to from the blog post, so it's not selected users that are answering.

Comment: @Raedwald dictating the desired narrative to a few interns and having them write something up is even easier. No surprises. I know people who used to have their doctors do that. Works well till the disease catches up and you have to explain unscheduled hospital visits.

Comment: No, not starting now. You won't hear them answering the questions they need to. It'll only be communiques.

Comment: To be fair, there is [a survey up](https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/Z2YDMRD). And with free form text fields with space for at least 581 characters. *There* is the chance to directly influence decisions makers. Make it count.

Comment: @PeterMortensen "directly" might be [overstating things a tad](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339119/how-will-stack-exchange-get-the-resources-to-track-and-handle-all-the-new-feedba/339128#339128) - those free form text fields are going to be fed through a coding algorithm to convert them to generic versions and *then* fed to the Data Team who will use them to produce overall trend information and those trends are what will influence decision makers.

Answer (score 43):

There are already many great answers so I won't repeat what's already been said.

I am all for inclusivity, but the *Through the loop* survey makes me feel excluded.

---

> "8. How many years have you been coding (including formal education,
> self-taught experience, bootcamps, MOOCs, etc.)?"

And really, after taking another look, all the questions are worded "Stack Overflow". My last activity there was 4 years ago. I can't and shouldn't be answering what I like/dislike about SO because my experience of it is incredibly dated. So... what am I supposed to answer? Are my answers going to be considered if I specify that I'm answering the question with my little corner of Stack Exchange in mind?

---

I did find out about the Stack Exchange communities because I had questions about code, but these questions are a minor reason of the reason why I'm here. I've asked questions about all sorts of topics here and always found great people to help me. By focusing on users' coding experience, you run the risk of alienating many other great communities hosted on Stack Exchange.

### Please lead by example and be inclusive of all of your communities.

Comment: Without the developer community propping up the network, the other communities wouldn't exist here.

Comment: @KevinB That's no reason to exclude the other communities.

Comment: @KevinB Of course, it brings a lot of traffic to other communities. But I don't believe for one second that only developers are answering my questions about biology, cooking, stats, graphic design, writing...

Comment: You're not being excluded. It's an open ended question. Answer 0 if the answer is 0.

Comment: @KevinB My point is it's an irrelevant question. Where is the question about how much time I've invested in communities here? (Maybe it's in the next pages, I don't know because I stopped answering there).

Comment: It is relevant, to the majority of people who will be taking the survey.

Comment: @KevinB Sure, I don't disagree there. How is that inclusive?

Comment: It's no more or less inclusive than any of the other questions. Why does that matter?

Comment: It was the last question.  So I referred back to my 4th grade LOGO class, so my opinion would matter.

Comment: Don't forget that a large proportion of SE staff don't even know the SE network exists.

Comment: @curiousdannii I seem to recall reading that somewhere but can't remember where. It's so baffling to me that they wouldn't know that there's something else outside of SO.

Comment: It is probably because the tension with beginners on Stack Overflow (at odds with the original objective of a (non-redundant) high-quality knowledge repository) is considered *the* major problem (e.g. at the root of [the first Twitter incident](https://medium.com/@Aprilw/suffering-on-stack-overflow-c46414a34a52)).

Comment: As I understand it, StackOverflow pays most of the bills, and only a few other sites achieve financial break-even.

Answer (score 43):

<sub>Yes, this is a sock account. I've deleted my previous account but could not resist answering this.</sub>

"You", unless otherwise specified, refers to Stack Exchange, not the asker of the question.

When I saw "feedback mechanisms", the first thing that came to mind was a much needed improvement to the way new users get feedback. Especially when announced alongside changes such as the vote value change and the post notice update, that's not too unreasonable. Is it?

Apparently, it is. I'm not the only person to suspect that this means the end of meta as we know it. To a certain degree, that would've been fine. Meta has not scaled well at all. SE has complained about low participation on meta, but **how is this supposed to improve anything**? You're not just removing the ability to participate, you're weighting it by gender, race, and age. One fantastic thing about meta was that the identity of the person asking was never of any significant concern, with a few exceptions like questions where for an instance LGBTQ+ members were asked.

Other people have already raised the same concern as me, but for what it's worth, here's another voice:

## Please don't do this to the community!

Leaving a tiny group of people to make decisions will only lead to further exclusion, where which group that is at risk is at the hands of whichever mods are in charge, and whatever messed up system you're using to determine which feedback matters more than others.

We've been ignored for years. By taking feedback out of sight, it just means it's harder to tell when things are ignored. Does that seem fair to you? Our moderators are amazing people, but they are still human. They make mistakes, they have opinions. If moderator elections turn into an entirely political election, what's the point? Moderators were elected to moderate and help [as exception handlers.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/):

> From the very first version of Stack Overflow faq way back in mid-2008, our goal has always been to give power back to the community:

...

> Moderators are human exception handlers, there to deal with those (hopefully rare) exceptional conditions that should not normally happen, but when they do, they can bring your entire community to a screaming halt — if you don’t have human exception handling in place.

You're now stripping the community of its power and diverging from the path you originally set out on. You need to think about what you want to be when you grow up and share it with the community instead of quietly pushing change after change without listening to the main group that drives this site: the community.

Comment: That's the problem: when we really love something, we get attached. To the point where we leave, to then come back. The energy and motivation by community members is outstanding ... one keeps wondering how they can keep "reading all of it" but still act in the ways they do.

Comment: I have a reasonable guess to who this is. Glad to see you back, and I wish it was under better circumstances.

Answer (score 39):

## The Loop is an attempt at silencing the community

"The Loop" is not a product designed to solve a problem that the community is facing, but a problem that Stack Exchange, Inc. is facing: **The Community**.

By implementing "The Loop", Stack Exchange, Inc. can avoid listening to Meta completely. They can quarantine Meta away, as "a toxic place where toxic people meet to discuss toxic ideas about how toxic they are towards Stack Exchange", and instead implement any feedback via "The Loop", a process designed to completely eliminate discussion, accountability or transparency.

### The Loop removes discussion

The Loop doesn't give users the ability to make their voices heard. By placing everything into a pre-formatted questionnaire, SE, Inc. controls precisely what is being asked, and who gets to hear it.

Questions that would sound overly critical of SE, Inc. as a business, such as "[Is SE, Inc. still interested in cooperating with the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333965/firing-mods-and-forced-relicensing-is-stack-exchange-still-interested-in-cooper)", would simply not be there.

Furthermore, there is no way for the community to talk to each other, and for SE, Inc. to be a part of that. A clear separation between community and staff is what SE, Inc. wants, but it's not in the best interest of the community.

### The Loop removes accountability

On Meta, questions and answers are public and for everyone to see. If staff makes a controversial decision, people are aware of it and can voice their criticism. It can be shown, in hard numbers, how many people are for or against something.

The Loop aims to remove this "problem", by giving SE, Inc. the ability to just refer to "the Loop" as the be-all-end-all entity that governs all decisions.

> We here at Stack Exchange, Inc. are happy to announce *[whatever thing]* because the data we gathered through the Loop indicates it's the best thing to do.

However, we can't see that data - only SE, Inc. does. So it's impossible for us to verify if any of these statements are true or not.

### The Loop eliminates transparency

In a rather controversial decision, the loop requires participants to disclose [race, age and gender](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339094/why-is-the-loop-survey-asking-about-race-age-and-gender). Now imagine, for a moment, SE, Inc. would decide that the opinions of certain groups, such as straight, white men, just doesn't count, and filters all of them out.

I'm not claiming that this is what SE, Inc. does, just that the Loop enables this kind of behavior much more easily. With their recent focus on "pronouns", it's not too far off to claim that SE, Inc. represents a very liberal (in the [US sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_liberalism_in_the_United_States)) ideology, focused more and more on minorities they perceive to be "victims" in one sense or another. It's not too far-fetched to assume that SE, Inc. has implemented "the Loop" and it's required identification of race, age and gender, in order to "give marginalized groups a bigger voice" - which is their euphemism for "giving everyone else less of a voice".

Comment: Could not agree more.

Comment: And let's add: *The Loop doesn't eliminate toxicality.* ... At least for me, the more I feel pushed to reduce my feedback into single sentences on such surveys, the higher the chance of snarky, toxic replies.

Comment: Toxicity will always exist, and no system in the world can remove it. Regardless of your policies, some people will get mad and say mean things. The only thing staff can do realistically is to grow thicker skin and deal with it.

Comment: I think the time will come soon when new users will be asked to disclose their race, gender and sexuality (including pronouns) when registering for a new _social_ Stack Exchange account.

Comment: @Joseph Race: White, Gender: Male, Sexuality: Straight. `Whoops! Looks like there was an error while trying to register. Try again later, please!`

Answer (score 34):

## Apparently, I belong to a minority:

> [image]

## There is more to the Stack Exchange network than just Stack Overflow.

If the goal of this survey was to make me (along with the users of the vast majority of SE's public sites) unwelcome, unwanted, and discriminated against -- by the very company that's making such a big show of patting y'selves in the back for working in the name of welcomeness -- then that goal was definitely achieved.

There's plenty more to find offensive in that blog post, and I'm staggered by the amazing amount of *additional* community debt that SE is taking on with its refusals to listen, but this one here really takes the cake, I must say.

Comment: Let's be real for a second: Stack Exchange, Inc. doesn't give the slightest fuck about any site other than Stack Overflow. That's where the money comes from.

Answer (score 33):

For once, I don't hate the latest (community-related) blog post… It sounds promising. *Just* promising, but promising nonetheless.

People at the company seem to have recognized that users of these sites — and *these* sites in particular — are not easily spoon-fed sweeping statements along the lines of "We know because they tell us," as [Jay Hanlon did in April 2018](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/), regarding "those in marginalized groups" feeling "less welcome". Without *any* data to back that up.

Or as [Sara Chipps did earlier this year](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/18/building-community-inclusivity-stack-overflow/), in July 2019, singling out statements such as "Caustic community for new users" from the developer survey. As if *that's* representative data.

Now, at least, there *is* data. "Unwelcoming community" tops the list of frustration with 10.6%. That's a *number* I can believe. That's about the number of people, in my personal experience, whose ego easily bruises when faced with the reality that they're not as smart as they think they are. 10 percent, give or take, that checks out.

For the record, I do *not* think that this number varies in any significant way across different demographics. In fact, I'd stipulate that it would be sexist / racist / whatever-ist to assume otherwise.

But it *is* a noble goal to try and get that number down. Not to zero, that would be an illusion. But maybe… 5%? 2%? Something like that.

And the only viable top-down approach is to improve the site's design, mechanics, usability, tools, feedback, etc. That makes sense.

Because let's not pretend that Meta is the best tool for… any of those things. In fact, it's a poor substitute for almost all of them. Like, nobody in their right mind tracks bugs on a Q&A site. It's just not done. You want representative user feedback: run unobtrusive surveys. Instead of letting a few extroverts in the community speak for everyone else.

This is a step in the right direction. I'm curious to see where they'll go from here.

Comment: Jaydles did have numbers to back up his assertion on that terrible blog post,  IIRC, from SE user surveys, and (non quantitative) information from (I guess) messages to moderators and direct to the company.

Comment: "Like, nobody in their right mind tracks bugs on a Q&A site." exactly. I don't get the negativity here ... If I understand the blog post correctly, SE will handle all the support for us that we were doing for them, and we can now waste even more time on endless discussions ... ;)

Comment: Challenge ahead. SO is getting prepared as a company (brand) - https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/TeamBlogFeedback/issues/162

Comment: User surveys are self-selecting, not representative.

Comment: I read @Arun's link, and find it fascinating to discover the Microsoft has chosen _not_ to use Stack Exchange technology, because Stack Exchange does not prioritise localisation and _supporting non-English character sets_ (?!). It's US-centric. All while they go around virtue signalling about how old-fashioned and racist and sexist we all are. Seriously?!

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica It might be more productive to give your feedback about Stack Exchange to Microsoft Q&A.

Comment: @rockwalrus-stopharmingMonica Why? It's not feedback about Microsoft.

Comment: @LightnessRaceswithMonica Microsoft is using Stack Exchange's design as a start, but they're actively trying to avoid its flaws.

Answer (score 27):

I want to respond to the "fundamental challenges on Meta" named in the blog post:

> ### The problem
>
> We have identified these fundamental challenges with Meta as we’ve grown and accrued community debt:
>
> 1. It’s hard to capture structured feedback on Meta. There are now so many conversations that we aren’t often able to participate. As a result, users end up not feeling heard and a lot of confusion (including some misinformation) is generated.

It's hard to take this problem statement seriously when your first survey in "The Loop" has exactly two questions asking for feedback:

> What do you like best about using Stack Overflow?
>
> What do you find most frustrating or unappealing about using Stack Overflow?

How exactly is that "more structured"?

How will users "end up feeling heard" better by using a black box to drop their feedback into?

> 2. On Meta, there are discussions, some that go on for a long time without a clear answer.

Why is that a challenge?  Unless you're trying to use Meta as an issue tracker.  But that was never its purpose.

> 3. Meta tends to exclude people that aren’t super immersed in the Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange culture.

I believe that is true of almost any feedback mechanism.  Why do you imagine you'll get a greater response rate from some other mechanism, or that it will give you more valuable information than *reading what your most engaged, community-oriented readers have to say?*

> 4. Meta requests don’t integrate with any existing ticketing system, so our Community Managers need to prioritize the best they can and answer the threads deemed most important at the time.

This seems a somewhat valid concern, but the votes on Meta posts should give you at least some indication of importance and community interest in problems raised.

Comment: But a Q&A site is a poor fit for a meta site.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Q&A as it's done on meta has one big advantage, all the single Qs are focused. "What do you like best about using Stack Overflow?" is the opposite of focused and would be closed as too broad. The connection between the different Qs is kind of the problem, I think.

Answer (score 26):

The last time I filled in a questionnaire for stack overflow it contained a question about gender. I filled in the gender non-conforming option (effectively turning me, a white male, to be classified among the gender minorities in the statistics).

We all know what happened after that.

Stack Overflow found out that [1.2% of their visitors/respondents](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#developer-profile-_-gender) do not associate with the standard male/female category boxes (instead: Non-binary, genderqueer, or gender non-conforming). Besides that one question, the report of that questionnaire is loaded with gender aspects (making it appear as if the decision about 'gender=important' was made *before* the results of questionaire). It seems like that (among other things) steered them into making extreme measures to make non-binary people feel more welcomed.... regardless what the outcome of the questionnaire does!

And now it is a mess.

---

> We want to address all these things and be **transparent** about how we’re paying down some of this community debt.

Questionnaires like these are just hiding the issues behind a pile of imprecise numbers and allows management to make decisions without actually talking to the users of the websites and the contributors that generate the content of the website.

---

So what do I think about this questionnaire:

*The more distance the better.*

Questionnaires like these make sure that no staff member needs to go chat with people on meta or elsewhere. A management tool to hide incompetence in communication.

Answer (score 25):

How was it decided that the following three should be grouped together: "Native American, Pacific Islander, or Indigenous Australian"?

Doing a google for this phrase gives pretty much only Stack Overflow/Exchange results, from the results of surveys from past years.

If the answer is “We consulted expert X and they said Y and Z”, that’s fine, I don’t expect Stack Exchange to do their own research, but I’d like to know the rationale.

**Update** In the 2020 developer survey, the following option was given, to a question which didn't use the word "racial" or "ethnicity":

> Indigenous (such as Native American, Pacific Islander, Or Indigenous Australian)

This would suggest that in 2019, the designers of The Loop thought back then that the three groups had that characteristic in common.

Comment: Presumably, those are all "Indigenous Peoples."  Natives, in other words.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm isn't that obvious? They are all of the same 'race'.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus at the end you drop a \s

Comment: If we're grouping like this, why not go one tiny step further and provide only the following options for Race: (1) Privileged (2) Marginalized? Thinking about it, those options could be reused for the other questions.

Comment: Now made into a question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339467/how-were-the-racial-backgrounds-used-by-the-loop-and-previous-surveys-designed

Answer (score 23):

So, hot on the heels of the sound condemnation SO Inc received for using some highly sketchy gender profiling data as their driver for the recent Question reputation changes they decide that it would be a good idea to do some straight-up ethnic and gender profiling data gathering of their own.

This time it's in the form of a yet another word salad blog post and a survey that would fall short of the quality I'd expect from an intern on their first day.

The blog post hits many of the talking points that have become *de rigour* in recent times, and to my ears they are sounding increasingly hollow -

> create an experience that works for all users

Just so long as "all" doesn't include the experienced and long serving members of the community who have been leaving the network in droves, the members of the lavender community who have felt driven from the network, the moderators who have been disenfranchised and cast aside and so on.

> We’d like to share with you some of the reasons why we make decisions and what inputs we listen to

I'd sarcastically quip something like "that would be a first!", except SO Inc used to do just that. Using the "Rewarding the Askers" fiasco as the most recent example I think this actually translates as "We'll come up with whatever saccharine tripe we think will make us look good."

> as well as give you a place to weigh in

What a brilliant idea! Perhaps you could have a Q&A site for the network where users can weigh in and staff (sorry *Stackers* - so. much. cringe.) could see what the community thinks and respond where appropriate. Think about it - you could even have a separate such site for each of the sites in the network to let the differing needs of the sites be reflected.

> show everyone how we think about serving the larger developer and technical community

Finally something that actually sounds like honesty - albeit in a backhanded, inferred way. It's no secret that the non-SO stacks and the non-technical ones in particular aren't anything more than second-class citizens at best. Tolerated in order to keep precious, precious traffic from disappearing off to Quora or Reddit when they have a query that's not coding related. It's a good thing that SO Inc aren't bothering to keep up the pretense of caring. It must have been so tiring for them.

> be clear about the “why” behind our decisions

Oh, my sides.

> If you’ve been with us for a long time, you may remember when our research process involved regular, direct exchanges between users and staff on Meta. Today, this process has been largely replaced by 1:1 user interviews, as well as other methods like surveys and contextual research.

So SO Inc.. how's that working out for you? Obviously not great since they now want to "fix" this by creating a working group of users to ask them things, essentially like meta but with one key difference that is shown by these two phrases:

> We’ll hand-select folks..

and,

> identified the people we would like to recruit

Factoring in the ethnic and gender profiling from the Loop survey this means either a) they want to do some good old fashioned virtue signalling and show off how they've got this special group of wonderfully diverse people that they engage with and trot them out in front of the world like show ribbons on a prize hog or b) they want an echo chamber sitting ready to rubber stamp whatever plans they have and are covering themselves from any accusations of discrimination.

> I'm not racist, some of my <strike>best friends</strike> working group members are black!

Of course if the are to do this they need to get rid of the inconvenient existence of Meta. And yes Meta isn't working great right now - but the reasons that the blog gives don't quite hold up.

> It’s hard to capture structured feedback on Meta. There are now so many conversations that we aren’t often able to participate. As a result, users end up not feeling heard and a lot of confusion (including some misinformation) is generated.

Users aren't feeling heard - because they aren't *being* heard. Staff don't *need* to participate in all conversations, that's just a Nirvana fallacy, the voting system and other activity metrics already give them a good guide as to what threads are worth looking at for them. In the last three days or so there has been <50 new questions posted on MSE, heck many people get more emails than that a day. It has nothing to do with *ability* to participate in what's important - it's all about a *willingness* to participate.

> On Meta, there are discussions, some that go on for a long time without a clear answer.

Maybe, *maybe* if someone at SO Inc decided to step up and provide some clarity that would help? Others are discursive and will never get a clear answer, but that's okay - they can be disengaged from if necessary.

> Meta tends to exclude people that aren’t super immersed in the Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange culture.

In many ways this is true - but how do you solve a problem of exclusion but creating a system that excludes even *more* people? Both the putative users working group and "moderator council" are by definition going to be even smaller subsets of users than those who engage in Meta.

> Meta requests don’t integrate with any existing ticketing system, so our Community Managers need to prioritize the best they can and answer the threads deemed most important at the time.

You mean, paid employees might actually have to do some work? Things aren't just going to be delivered neatly wrapped in a big shiny bow?

Not that this matters anyway since..

> We plan to transition things like bug reports, user and customer support, user feedback, and company announcements off of Meta over the course of next year.

So that's that then. The decision has been made, the gish has been galloped and RIP Meta. It wasn't perfect, it could have been better, but I guess we'll never know.

**PS:** Such a minor thing in the context of this car crash of a blog post, but I do wish they'd stop it with the pathetic twisting of everything into tortured IT analogies "community debt" (like technical debt..see! see!) "human in the loop" (it's from Machine Learning, that's hip now right?). I'm not sure whether it's because they think that their entire audience is made up of developers (not true) and that developers can only understand things in IT terms (also not true) or whether they think it's "cool" or "quirky" or something. Either way it's almost as cringey as "Stackers" (which is surely the cringiest term for a group of employees since Apple started referring to their in-store support staff as "Geniuses") and I wish it would go away.

Answer (score 20):

I think everything has looped back to [Meta is Murder](https://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder/) phase. Wondering how long it takes to get back to

> When the co-founder of Stack Exchange responds to your meta post –
>   even if it wasn't exactly what you may have wanted to hear – I hope it
>   speaks volumes about how committed we are to really, truly building
>   this thing alongside our community. [[1]](https://blog.codinghorror.com/listen-to-your-community-but-dont-let-them-tell-you-what-to-do/)

If ever. Because at the moment we're more like at

> When the employees are exempt from participating in to meta discussions –
>   even if you'd like to hear literally anything that isn't marketing/corporate lingo – I hope it
>   speaks volumes about how committed we are to really, truly building
>   this thing alongside our community.

Answer (score 20):

I'm not a fan. Now I don't have a crystal ball to see what they're going to do with this data, but in light with recent events and the general tone deafness they've displayed this doesn't bode well for us.

I guess time will tell what comes out of it, but it's not a great look to start "rebuilding of trust" by snubbing everyone openly. I'm not a fan of even less transparency, which is what this is. I hope at least the working group will be public in who gets to be a member, why they're selected and their recommendations and feedback will also be public.

We need substantially more transparency at every step of the decision making process, and this is a way in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 20):

My feedback to their feedback:

**A subset of users with more influence (aka Working group)**

It seems to destroy the cohesion of the community and puts the company in control of the whole process. Feels a bit like unpaid beta testing to me. I would have the feeling I'm working for the company, not for the community and I wouldn't probably want to do that.

Not even sure I understood what the problem is. Somehow they are not able to process all the feedback that they are getting through meta??

**A subset of moderators with more duties (aka Moderator advisor group)**

It seems to destroy the cohesion of the moderators and puts even more working burden on those moderators. I genuinely hope they get paid for this because doing it is a lot of work. The community moderator roles here become more and more like the role of company employees.

I understand the problem though. Documenting the moderator experience and process is nice. But I thought that is a task for employees of the company.

**Migrating bug reports and other stuff off of meta (but where?)**

"There are now so many conversations that we aren’t often able to participate." I don't understand what the problem is. I thought SO has grown a lot in the last time employee-wise and so the ability to participate in conversations should have improved. Is the problem too much feedback?

"Meta requests don’t integrate with any existing ticketing system" That could probably be achieved with reasonable effort. Just scan meta once per week and update/synchronize with any existing ticket system.

As a complement to meta I can see many good things coming from ticketing systems etc. but otherwise I feel like the cohesion of the community is destroyed and discussions will be almost impossible then.

Just think about what you give up in return. All the good ideas of the community. In a way that is like the opposite of listening.

**Miscellaneous issues**

Some users may value their privacy (like their gender, age, ...) and by asking them for it or weighting feedback by it, you may miss out on them. For example, the exact gender composition of the users isn't really known and also shouldn't be. That may be a problem for the whole process.

The name is very fancy and may be misleading. Why do cooperations always come up with a fancy name for something that turns out to be just some ordinary kind of survey?

It became clear in the last years that feature request are largely ignored. I fear the new system will not change this much. Surely a ticketing system gives some kind of statistical overview but it doesn't magically increase the number of technical people working on the stuff, or does it?

By relying on a selected subset of users for feedback instead of the whole community you kind of lose signal. I understand the idea to kind of make it more representative of the whole community, but depending on the size of the subset (should be at least some thousands of users to be diverse enough I would guess) the loss of total signal might still outweigh any improvement in composition.

Taking more control might speed up the whole process on the company side, which might be a good thing, but it decreases the sense of community and self-determination of the community. Will I be happy to be a small input sensor with all the subsequent analysis and decisions be made by someone else? Now at least I can vote on things a bit. And if the whole community members aren't happy, will they participate? Will the result be as good as before or maybe even worse?

"..north of 100k new users signing up to the public Q&A each month.." This is somewhat misleading or not very informative because the net inflow of new users is probably much smaller (would need to account for all the old users not being seen any more). A historic trend series of net inflow of users would give more context here.

Answer (score 17):

If possible, I'd like to see another question in that survey, along the lines of:

> 9. **Is this your first time giving feedback to Stack Overflow, the company?**
>
>    - yes
>    - no, I have previously:
>
>      - written on Meta (site-specific or general Meta)
>      - used the "contact us" link
>      - (other applicable)
>    - prefers not to reply

I think it fits within the "new feedback mechanism" to gather some info about the before/after. **I'd really like some stats about how much "new, fresh" feedback there is.**

Plus it might inform unaware people of the previous feedback mechanism in place.

Comment: You could add "@'d a developer/community manager on twitter" as a form of previously giving feedback.

Answer (score 17):

I love the fact that, at the time I'm writting this, the loop has absolutely *no comments*.

For something that is supposed to enhance communication, that is incredibly ironic.

Comment: It has probably "pending" comments: https://twitter.com/carnivivre/status/1199041153871613952

Comment: Oh, they're definitely cherry picking comments there. My mildly sarcastically criticism of the "working group" plan didn't pass moderation.

Comment: @jmoerdyk Neither did mine saying this was a terrible idea.

Comment: @jmoerdyk See my thoughts: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339173/285661

Comment: @jmoerdyk or mine asking if the race question in the survey was suppose to be a "nationality" or "race" question and was going to be split or not. As of this writing, every single comment is praising the idea (which seems impossible just based on a quick sample of older blog posts)

Comment: Yes, the comments on the blog either have an overwhelmingly positive reaction to The Loop, or they are not really relevant. There’s an enormous disconnect between the published feedback on the blog and the feedback here, on Meta. I assume that’s what staff is referring to as the “toxic” or “non-inclusive” Meta community. Is this SE’s idea of “inclusivity” — avoiding any criticism? This is exactly what escalated this entire mess. Yet another indicator that SE doesn’t care about the community at all, if you ever needed one.

Comment: @jmoerdyk: You may have to make it very subtle ([like TechLead](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODaq-JEiIKg) (YouTube)).

Answer (score 17):

Looks like they are trying to shut down dissent.

Note how the last few big changes were not posted on Meta. SE staff gets destroyed by downvotes and criticism on their horrible ideas. **They don't want real feedback anymore.**

---

Unless we contact their employers and convince them of the imminent threat to <del>the SE network</del> their money, this place will turn into another internet dumpster in a few years and we will be completely unable to prevent it.

Comment: Re *"their horrible ideas"*: But the problem is they would also get downvoted for fantastic ideas. The meta crowd is also at fault for being extremely conservative, resisting change (no matter what it is) to an extreme degree.

Comment: @PeterMortensen could you provide a couple of examples of the good ideas that got downvoted?

Comment: The recent weight change to question votes was public. But that is of course not a big change.

Answer (score 16):

> Long-time users can be surprised by things changing out of the blue
>   for reasons they don’t understand, ..

So can short-time users.  It wasn't so long ago that SE was insisting that people who do not regard themselves as ***traditional she*** or ***traditional he*** should not feel excluded, and to ensure that, promulgated a Pronoun Policy (since somewhat modified) and demoted and libeled one of SE's most respected moderators (still not corrected.)

And that mess (***The*** Mess) goes on.

**Now the first question in SE's latest missile to the troops asks: are you a she or are you a he?**

What happened to inclusivity?  Are gender-specific pronouns now OK? Is Monica going to be reinstated?  Was The Mess just a bad dream?

Comment: That does not look fair to me. Actually the question is: are you a he or a she or not or something else or a combination of the above?

Comment: @Stop harming Monica  It is possible that I read it too fast.  It is also possible that SE changed it after I read it (about 08:30 EST 11/26/19) and before you read it.

Comment: Maybe. Looks like it was written in a hurry and then repeatedly corrected after the release.

Answer (score 15):

## What does this have to do with "We're rewarding question askers?"

The [recent blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) which announced the change in reputation gains for question upvotes hinted at the release of this feedback mechanism, but I somehow got the impression, from both the context and comments [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/338140/657008) that you'd, like, give feedback to people who are relevant in that discussion: the people asking bad questions. A nice start on the path of working with the community is trying to fix issues we want fixed, like the flood of low-quality questions, rather than giving us a new feedback mechanism which won't even let us point that out.

That blog post is hence fairly misleading, and I was hyped because I thought we'd get  better moderation tools and instead we get a message that the company will cherry-pick people who will give them advice.

Answer (score 5):

I'm fine with this...this gives us some insight into what their plans are and how they're planning on improving **Stack Overflow**.

I should quantify this - from the announcement this looks like it concerns **Stack Overflow** at large, as opposed to the rest of the Stack Exchange network.  This makes sense since that's what keeps the lights on the network on, and is easily the most influential network site by **several** orders of magnitude, no matter how you wanna slice the data.

From a value perspective, it's logical to invest into something which will provide more money or pay for other investments elsewhere.  To put it in another way, there's no reason to spend $1,000 on a pet project when you can't make rent.

To answer the questions you posed...

> Do you see that "the loop" can work and lead us to a "place" that works for "us" community?

It can, but there's a *lot* of calcified views out there.  The big thing to balance (and this is a hard thing to balance) is that there are at least three perspectives to keep in mind at any one point in time - the community who *uses* the site (asking questions, getting answers and that's about it), the community who *maintains* the site (upvoting, downvoting, other moderation activities) and the company who, somehow, has to keep the whole thing paid for.

The issue I see is that there's a lot of noise in with the signal.  I get that not a lot of us are happy that the company kind of disappeared on us for years at a time, and a lot of change has happened.  [I'm no stranger to that sensation.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/373160/1079354)

However, the problem that needs to be solved is not an easy one - how do we make this community work for users who just want answers to their questions, users who want to maintain and encourage *good* questions, and the company who has to keep the lights on?  On top of that, how do we balance the perspectives of all involved parties who have an obvious stake in this whole matter such that everyone can walk away feeling satisfied?

That's a process that needs time and effort and commitment from all parties involved.  There's no silver bullet for that.

> If so, how does your vision "on top" of "the loop" look like?

The big thing is that there will have to be compromise on all sides.  The group of curators isn't always going to get their way, nor is the company or the group of others who ask questions, get answers and disappear.  It's going to take time, and it's going to take a lot of energy to see and effect real change.

But it'll be slow.  Not a lot of people are going to be satisfied with "slow", but I don't see this moving any faster than that.

Answer (score 1):

Let's face it, **Meta.SE is dysfunctional** for communicating with SE staff (and also for SE users who are not hugely familiar).  No matter what SE staff post, the community is going to pile on and mercilessly yell at them.

It's a hostile and toxic environment for SE staff, and it's plausible that OH&S regulations regarding mental health come into play.  **SE staff have taken steps to involve the community in a somewhat-democratic way that reduces the harm to their own mental health**.

It's not fantastic, but the days of SE staff being our chums are gone.  It's better than being ignored entirely.

Comment: This is a decent point, but (for the most part) activity on meta's involve criticising ideas, and as long as the line between attacking ideas and personal attacks is made clear (and appropriate action is taken when the line is genuinely crossed), I don't see how points can't be pulled out and improved upon (or even just talked about by the community and staff members). The outrage is happening because the community is feeling like it's not being listened to, and it seems like The Company are content with tightening the feedback loop in order to avoid what it may lead to anyway: a mass exodus

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow. Albeit that announcement also came a bit late, and could have gone to MSO, positive feedback, constructive answers. And if you want to see something nice: search my answer there and read what the SE staffer has to say about it on Twitter. Also note for example that the apology MSE entry by David Fullerton first received hundreds of upvotes, before that turned around. Thus your premise about merciless yelling is a at least oversimplified, if not misleading.

Comment: "_Meta.SE is dysfunctional for communicating with SE staff_" on the contrary, because of the constructive feedback on the survey, SE staff have taken swift action to update their latest survey (missing options, missing ethnic groups). Also be reminded that SE staff are adults, not infants; they are able to deal with criticism and dissenting reactions.

Comment: Re *"No matter what SE staff post, the community is going to pile on and mercilessly yell at them"*: Yes, that is the crux of the matter. It should not be difficult to design a better system for meta (a Q&A system with immediate voting on every post is not a good fit). But it will (unfortunately) probably be closed down entirely instead. Let us hope it will not be replaced by something substandard. But I would really like to see Stack Exchange set a new standard for different kind of sites than Q&A sites, including meta sites. Like they did with the original software in 2008.

Comment: *"No matter what SE staff post, the community is going to pile on and mercilessly yell at them"* There was a time, just a few years ago, when it was pretty much the opposite: whatever choice SE inc made, people were only delivering words of praise. And they are exactly the same people. So maybe (just maybe) the backlash they experience now happens because they became completely disconnected from their community. It didn't come out of the blue. And the disagreements *really* mean something: it's certainly not just because people now like to complain.

Comment: While I too think Meta turning into a place hostile to employees was mostly the company's own making, it is certainly true that it has been dysfunctional for a long long time and an overhaul something like this was long overdue. It's just that for me personally, the past few months destroyed so much trust, I can't have any faith in the new process. And a hard time seeing why I should contribute to it, because while I accept SE staff can't be our chums any more, there is a wider community to include, etc., as a volunteer I expect the company to stick to a basic standard of decency.

Comment: Yes meta is dysfunctional but surveys are no replacement. Getting rid of the Q&A format for meta and replace it with more traditional forums like Reddit etc where you can keep track of discussion threads would work better.

Comment: I can't really downvote that answer, because that would look hostile but I also can't upvote it because I disagree. I think I remember upvoted posts from company employees in the last months. I'm relatively sure that if company employees would have posted and explained more in the last moths, they would have gotten a much better reception.

Comment: @Trilarion Just so you know, down-voting is not considered _hostile_ just yet.

Comment: Hard disagree with this. When the CTO came out and gave an announcement that *resonated positively* with people, it got what it deserved: praise. It turns out it was a whole load of horseshit, but that's a different matter.

Comment: '*No matter what SE staff post, the community is going to pile on and mercilessly yell at them.*' - This is utter nonsense and is just plain and simply WRONG, and provably so too. Look at how the new post rollout was taken. Try sort questions by the highest voted and see how many (ex) staff posts come at the top. As is with all posts, good posts get acknowledged and bad posts get critiqued. I'm not even going to touch the allegations of MSE being "toxic" because it would just take too long.

Comment: The demotion of Monica plus the subsequent tone-deaf reaction of SE followed by the total deafness of SE caused a [tipping point](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tipping%20point).

Comment: You want to know how people will stop criticizing SE, Inc's every move? If they stop doing shitty things! Do you think if SE, Inc's CEO would step forward and write a heart-felt apology about how sorry he is that the communication with the community is not working and adds a plan on how to fix it, the community will pile on him?