# Typo in category for “Black or of African descent”

Tags: bug, status-completed, the-loop

In the current version of The Loop, one of the options for racial background is spelt “Black or of African **decent**”, rather than “Black or of African **descent**”.

I tried notifying Sara Chipps by @ commenting her [yesterday](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339050/the-loop-has-arrived-what-does-the-community-think-about-it#comment1133545_339050), but didn’t get a response. (Maybe she doesn’t check her notifications often?) This was first noticed [a week ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339050/the-loop-has-arrived-what-does-the-community-think-about-it#comment1130842_339050).

I know that some users would rather that racial background doesn’t get asked at all - there’s another question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339094/why-is-the-loop-survey-asking-about-race-age-and-gender) about that. I know that some people think that “Black” shouldn’t be grouped with “African descent” - if nothing else, I assume it’s to make the option symmetrical with “White or of European descent”, an option which is preferred over just “White”. But can we agree on fixing a typo even if we can’t agree upon everything else?

Yes, it’s just a typo. But considering that in the previous version of the survey they had totally excluded this group, and that Stack Exchange has placed a strong emphasis on users being respectful to each other, the company taking a bit of effort to be respectful would be appreciated.

Comment: Sara hasn't seen your comment.  The last time she visited here was [Nov 27 at 14:34](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/139284/sara-chipps).

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention. We're looking into getting it fixed. Apologies for the delay. I'll hopefully have an update soon.

Comment: This should be fixed now.

Comment: Well it's a bug. Small bug. I don't like SE, I don't like what they do, but that one is a pure human error. The lack of review is indeed annoying, but that's what we, the ordinary users, are for.

Comment: @Shadow: If only the corporation had a way to solicit feedback and review from its user community, gather bug reports and discuss changes to the platform ... Oh, wait.

Comment: @Robert they just did here. It's sad that they kick it and closing meta, but we can use it while it lasts, at least.