# Will comments on "The Loop" blog posting be shared?

Tags: discussion, blog, the-loop

From [The Loop Blog Entry](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/)

> Our commitment to you, moving forward, is to continue to share reports
>   on what we’re learning here publicly on the blog.

I can't help noticing that after this has been up for a day, no comments have appeared.

I can certainly understand wanting to groom this message, but if the commitment to "sharing reports" is real, and the intention to move important decisions and announcements to a blog-centric mechanism, it would go a long way if the curtains are raised a bit and we can be shown how this is going to work.

For users like me, at the tipping point of deciding whether we're buying in or buying out, I suggest this be used as an example of how things are going to proceed so we can frame our choice.  The blog mechanism must have yielded a ton of comments.  Let's see some summary of some kind.  Have there been suggestions to improve the process?  Can we see a positive/negative breakdown?

Comment: What is this negative breakdown you speak of? Comments on the blog are moderated for a reason.

Comment: I don't think the substance of the comments moderated out of the blog are any different from what we can find here on meta. In short: they are probably overwhelmed by negative feedback on this.

Comment: @dim -- I agree, but if there is going to be a shift away from meta for this proposed blog-centric system, I'd like to see how it's going to "work"

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi -- I don't know what it will look like.  I suppose a simple thumbs up/thumbs down/neutral count, with periodic updates.  A pie chart or table showing trending categories of responses, if they could be categorized, would do it, too.  Even a written summary of what's being "learned"

Comment: I don't think they allow comments anymore on blogs, thats just leftover functionality from the platform.

Comment: The fact that "The Loop" was a blog post and not a meta question shows they do not want any feedback on anything they post. They want it to be a statement, not a conversation. IMO, Stack Exchange meta will be gone by the new year.

Comment: @mag -- there's a button to submit comments.  I haven't tried it, beyond clicking it and getting to some sort of window where they ask me for more information than my SE authentication, which seems kind of silly, so I stopped.

Comment: @Dev, probably not by the new year, but I don't think we will spend summer '20 together, if you get my drift.

Comment: @DevelopingDeveloper  that's my thought too, I just want to hear it before they're ready to say it.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Oh I 100% agree, but unfortunately we won't hear it.

Comment: IOW, the loop isn't intended to be closed.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi :'(

Comment: I hope they give us notice before they shut MSE down and it isn't just an impromptu blog post and curtains.

Comment: @Script47 Oh they will, just like Monica received notice why she was demoted and when we all received notice that they were considering changing the licensing

Comment: @Script, don't worry, there will be a prominent blog post about stances being maintained and goals being achieved and missions being accomplished, focusing on the inclusive and exciting new venues for community feedback. Then nothing as the network fades into obscurity.

Comment: Maybe we should start up a backup meta through Area51 ;)

Comment: @ScottSeidman That will be against the code of conduct, well I mean the future code of conduct

Comment: @ScottSeidman I suggest naming it stackexchange.stackexchange.com or stackexchangeusers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 32):

> I can't help noticing that after this has been up for a day, no comments have appeared.

I think that is pretty much "the usual"!

Last time, with the "question weights" announcement, the waiting period between me submitting my comments, and "moderation" clearing them was (at least) 24 hours. Interestingly enough, depending on what was entered where, I could sometimes see my pending comments when coming back to that blog page, sometimes not.

And of course, there is no notification whatsoever when "moderation" rejects a comment, thus: also no explanation *why* that comment was deemed unworthy.

Beyond that, it *seems* that SE Inc. considers that blog to be "fully on their turf". Meaning: it is not related in any way to the community. It is their "moderation", their rules, their whatever. We can only contribute content, and hope for the best.

In other words: the perfect new world order, at least according to SE Inc.

Answer (score 13):

As of the time of this answer (2019-11-26) it appears that comments are now starting to appear on the blog. Most are from 2019-11-26 but one is from 2019-11-25 so it may that there is a significant backlog that is being processed manually.

Comment: I wish we knew the policy-- is this all comments?  A random sample?  a cherry-picked sample?

Comment: @ScottSeidman - definitely not all the comments, as mine from yesterday morning has yet to appear.  My guess is very cherry-picked, with some mildly negative ones coming to put on a resemblance of being fair

Comment: Having never commented on the blog, I didn't realise this was the case. Wow, this is another level of disgusting. Creating an impression to the onlookers that the community is in support of all the crap that's been going on.