# Is Microsoft Q&A the beginning of the end for SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I saw Microsoft has [created its own Q&A system](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/teamblog/introducing-microsoft-qanda), designed to incorporate the same Stack Overflow-style Q&A, but with additional samples, documentation and tutorials.

Someone asked ["Why not use SO"](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/TeamBlogFeedback/issues/162) and got some interesting answers.

I assume MS Q&A isn't using SO as the backend platform, as 'saldana' said [they would continue to improve their platform to match SO's features](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/TeamBlogFeedback/issues/162#issuecomment-549598058).

I know there are other alternatives to Stack Overflow out there, such as [Devada's AnswerHub](https://devada.com/answerhub/features/) that has not gained nearly as much traction as Stack Overflow has, but Microsoft is a different beast.

If the community is being alienated so much they are creating their own Q&A site, and (I estimate) half the tech questions will start to be resolved on MS Q&A, is there going to be much left here soon?

Comment: Integration with GitHub could drive people to Microsoft Q&A

Comment: I hope so. Even if that means just getting regular feedback from people that care and can make changes.

Comment: I feel obliged to vote to close this.  While an interesting topic, the question itself *Is Microsoft Q&A the beginning of the end for SO?* is basically a request for speculation.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones How is that any different than half of the posts in Meta?

Comment: @RebeccaJStones it's about SO and how the community here will respond to an alternative. It's entirely appropriate to ask that question of the community here.

Comment: When there no longer is a place for "The single best Q/A site in the world", then there have to be *multiple* (not-so-good) Q/A sites. It wasn't soooo hard to see that coming.

Comment: `This question was closed Oct 31 at 7:16 PM by saldana for the following reason: Question is an exact copy of an Stack Overflow question.` It doesn't appear to be a programming site. There are no tags for languages, only for products or technologies.
 https://docs.microsoft.com/answers/questions/617/how-can-i-enumerate-an-infinite-sequence-of-intege.html

Comment: There is an [internal Stack Overflow at Microsoft](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMfxd9y0cMY&t=21m01s).

Comment: @ScottHannen they were [partnered up over docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/teamblog/stackoverflow-documentation-for-microsoft-developers#future-integration), but that [has been migrated away](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/teamblog/code-samples), and I think more will migrate too in the future. MS Q&A is very new right now, so its not surprising its comprehensive

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones fair enough, but the question was right at the end - if all the MS answers go to MS Q&A, will there be enough left to make SO feasible?

Comment: A good read [there](https://docs.microsoft.com/answers/questions/773/why-not-just-use-stack-overflow.html) to answer you

Comment: Competition is a good thing.  If SE is the only game in town, what motivation do they have to do better?

Comment: I brought the same for visibility in another post [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339050/the-loop-has-arrived-what-does-the-community-think-about-it/339086#comment1131064_339086)

Comment: Anecdote (too lazy for sources, sorry): back in my IBM days, there was a similar thing on developerWorks. Suspect it might be sunset soon. As far as I can remember it was internal only, and mostly used by support folks to ask and answer their own questions (often without proper sources or understanding, which led to some debatable workarounds). Also you couldn't downvote, which made the thing hardly usable.

Comment: More seriously though, while I think competition might be good, I believe the advantage of SE networks is quantifiable in **years** of curated content. How can even the most perfect platform compete with that, if it's starting just now?

Comment: @Zymus It literally is not. Some people just DO because they CAN :)

Comment: They specify "What are the major benefits of Microsoft Q&A versus Stack Overflow?" in their [FAQ](https://docs.microsoft.com/answers/articles/388/microsoft-qa-frequently-asked-questions.html). Basically they want to be able to associate product usage with the question asker. It's more like a support thing / help desk thing, I guess.

Comment: @Trilarion hah. Figures. "No thank you" then.

Comment: Since programming and technology does not revolve solely around Microsoft products, MS Q&A site will not have enough impact to bring SO down. It may reduce SO traffic in MS tags, but that is all. On the other hand, little competition from such big player can make SE management to think twice about their next moves, if they are thinking at all...

Comment: I hope they implement the BING search engine, that would be 6-8 times better then the SO search engine.

Comment: Hopefully this will drive away the bad questions from this site.

Comment: Well... when was the last time Microsoft released a successful product? Did they release Windows 3 before or after Excel?

Comment: @Lundin ho ho ho. I believe all of Stack Overflow is built with Microsoft technology. Is that count as successfull enough?

Comment: @gbjbaanb As in what, Visual J++, nowadays known as C# .NET? Wasn't a very successful release. They had to do retake it a lot of times.

Comment: Yahoo! Answers asked the same thing about SO 10 years ago ...

Comment: Even if it would reduce traffic to SO a little, there's still the rest of the SE network.

Comment: I can imagine how this may work in practice. MS Q&A will focus less on the question content and more on the products usage of the asker and give some general advice on how to use the products better. Some kind of trial and error. They could even make a flowchart. Which actually makes sense for support related stuff.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No. Their move was planned long time ago to replace the Technet & MSDN forum that were aging.

I am a moderator on Technet, and I can tell that it was move that was talked a lot in the past to resolve some issues.

The focus, as stated in answer linked is not the same as on SO. They welcome almost any question, and there are no downvotes or community moderation as it’s done by almost all by staffers; while on Stack Overflow the contents is more quality over quantity.

I think both platforms got their use (but maybe the "Welcome Wagon" of SO might scrap that balance)

A side note, the CoC of MS for the use is a lot simpler, it’s like the old be nice rule from SO.

Comment: Does Microsoft Q&A support all tech questions, or just those related to Microsoft tech?

Comment: @RobertHarvey [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/answers/questions/index.html) on the right hand side they have list of Supported Products. It's a whole bunch of Azure stuff, UWP and some Partnet Center API. So it's not even related to all Microsoft tech, but only a small subset of it. Underneath that list they say "For any products and services not listed above please continue using the current channels."

Comment: @RobertHarvey Q&A support is limited, in start of next year everything that MS forum support will move to it. If you mean in a generic's way; It's hard to give a accurate answer, support yes for programming language that are supported inside their products (c/c++,c#, etc..), but the difference is that offtopic question are guided to the correct place (In exemple I had recently some symantec questions inside my forum. I guided the users to go to the vendor's forum) To be more welcoming mean to see more of such questions, it's why I wonder what the Welcome Wagon will make SO look like in the end

Comment: Does it mean that quality answers from the new Microsoft Q&A cannot be expected?

Comment: @Trilarion You will have quality, but it will not come from peer pressure (downvote and such)

Comment: @yagmoth555-GoFoundMeMonica Could be although I somehow doubt it. The old MSDN forums had on average not much useful information as far as I remember. But maybe it works. I'm all for experiments.

Comment: _"while on Stack Overflow the contents is more quality over quantity"_ bahahahahahaha

Answer (score 9):

If you go to [Stack Overflow reputation league](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month) you can see that there is very little MS related technology on the first page for top earners in the last month, and even less MS related products that are currently covered with MS Q&A site.

Programming and technology don't solely revolve around Microsoft products and MS Q&A site will not have enough impact to bring SO down. It may reduce SO traffic in some MS tags, but that is all. It will also reduce pressure on SO by allowing questions that are off topic on Stack Overflow. Little less things to clean up is good thing, IMO.

On the other hand, little competition from such big player can make SE management to think twice about their next moves. MS can decide to expand support to its other products, including languages and that could be more serious threat to SO traffic. But even if that happens MS Q&A is nowhere near being the beginning of an end of SO.

Any kind of beginning of an end of SO will not come from the outside, but from inside the company. SO has huge traction and the only way it can collapse is under its own weight and because its own bad moves.

Comment: That's nice and all, but couldn't they simply buy Stack Overflow? It seems much easier to buy and rebrand than to build something from scratch.

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica They are not building SO, they are fulfilling their product support needs. It is not the first nor the last company that has some sort of Q/A around their technology and support (to different extent and different success)

Answer (score 8):

The way I see it - Microsoft has a [different goal in mind](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/TeamBlogFeedback/issues/162#issuecomment-548984237).

> However, Stack Overflow has specific criteria about what questions are appropriate for the community and Microsoft Q&A will have a more open policy regarding this. More importantly, via Microsoft Q&A we can create unique experiences that allow us to provide the highest level of support for our customers. It is hard to get a full picture of the customer who is asking a question on Stack Overflow. But on Microsoft Q&A it will be possible to connect the asker to their actual product usage and support contract. This will enable new opportunities to offer the highest quality support.

In this response, I take away the following:

- Microsoft Q&A wishes to have a more loose policy about what questions get asked on the site.
- Microsoft is *explicitly* leaning on this product as a means of supporting their products.  Stack Overflow is very much not suited for that.
- There's a lot of metadata that makes supporting Microsoft questions "noise" on Stack Overflow - namely, "actual product usage" and "support contract".  Those aren't details Stack Overflow cares about since support isn't the goal.

Besides, this has existed in one incarnation or another for their own products *anyway*.

**This isn't a threat to Stack Overflow in the *slightest***, but that's not to say that there aren't other groups out there who would seek to create their own platform.  Those that wish to face a daunting uphill battle in trying to pool together the actual resources needed to make something similar to the scale and utility of Stack Overflow, and frankly the only entity that could scratch the surface today would be Microsoft.

Although to be blunt, if it were the case that Microsoft wanted to truly ape the Stack Exchange experience, they'd just buy it like they did GitHub...

Answer (score 4):

> If the community is being alienated so much they are creating their own Q&A site, and (I estimate) half the tech questions will start to be resolved on MS Q&A, is there going to be much left here soon?

We might see a decrease in the *quantity* of new questions (about Microsoft-related technologies, which are much less than half of the traffic, as others have noted), but on the other hand, the *quality* of said questions may actually increase. They've stated the following:

> However, Stack Overflow has specific criteria about what questions are appropriate for the community and Microsoft Q&A will have a more open policy regarding this.

I hope the users who ask questions that are too open-ended or otherwise unfit to be answered on Stack Overflow will finally find a place where they can stay, instead of repeatedly trying their luck here until they reach the question ban.