# Have the October 2019 moderator removal procedures been used?

Tags: support, company, moderator-removal

Related: [Has the October 2019 moderator reinstatement process actually been used?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339510/336163)

In October of 2019, a [new set of processes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/336173/336163) were enacted to handle cases of potentially misbehaving moderators and warn them or remove their diamonds as applicable.

Have either the Action or Conduct processes been used? If so, are any outcome statistics available (e.g. fifteen moderators were put through the Action process, with three released with no penalties, three warned, four removed, and five still in process)? Have any problems been noted?

To be clear, I'm not seeking action or non-action against any specific moderator. What I'm asking is whether the new processes that were introduced with much fanfare and quite a bit of debate last year are actually getting used in day-to-day operations and how well they are meeting their stated goals and the goals of the company and community.

I'm also not asking for anyone's "dirty laundry" to be aired on Meta for all to see, so anonymized data or redacted case studies are fine.

In response to comments by Catija ♦, the question is fundamentally on whether the processes have been used, and if so, how they have worked out. I don't have any reason "why [I] think it might need to be changed", because *I don't currently know how well they are working*. If an answer indicates that the processes have largely become name-calling farces in which the end results were already well-known before the processes started, then that could lead to a suggestion by me (or someone else) that a change be implemented. If the processes are working well, that is all the more reason not to lightly propose major changes.

Comment: You're asking the wrong question. We're not going to answer whether it's been used or not. If you want to know if we're looking at changing the process, ask that. Explain why you think it might need to be changed. You don't need to know if it's been used or not to get the info you're looking for.

Comment: You are asking whether Stack Exchange, Inc. has suddenly started to follow their own processes? What a refreshingly new idea!

Comment: I don't think the new edit really changes the question at all. JG and Catija's answers should cover it.

Answer (score 8):

Moderator removals are *by right* (in terms of the letter and spirit of the rules), not something that's meant for SE to publicly discuss.

We've all seen what happens. Presumably an *angry* mod who left in poor standing is going to be complaining loudly. A moderator removed for the wrong reasons will result in quite a fuss. A moderator who messed up badly enough might keep quiet but the community would notice.

I guess the best way to work it out, is to see if the canary is still singing. I'm personally not aware of any *new* mod removals outside resignations. I've not heard anything. If you hear of it, its happened. Its not a *satisfying* answer but as far as I'm aware it hasn't been used, and this is in line with what we're experienced in the past.

Mod removals are *rare* and hopefully *continue to be so*.

Answer (score 6):

Knowing whether it's been used or not is not a question that we are going to answer. The important thing is that no one has been removed **without** the process or other known practices like moderator inactivity. We hope it will never need to be used but I'm not going to affirm whether or not it has been because it will immediately lead to speculation.

As to whether they will be revisited, they are more likely to be revisited in response to suggestions from y'all than from actual use. The need to remove a mod for any reason other than inactivity or at their request is extremely rare and generally noticed by at least the site they represented. Putting these policies in practice is... likely going to take decades before they have enough data to make educated changes... if ever.

So, if you want to change the policy, don't wait for data.

Comment: It’s not useful to know whether something has actually worked in practice the way it was intended to or whether it needed tweaks? The process was mentioned fairly prominently in a communication from the company; I don’t think questions about it should be viewed with so much hostility.

Comment: "We hope it will never need to be used" seems to confirm that it hasn't yet been used? Not that there's anything wrong with that; as you say, it's a good thing if it hasn't been necessary. If someone asks, "Has anyone used the new fire extinguishers to put out a real fire yet?", it's a legit answer to say "We're happy we haven't needed to yet".

Comment: @ColleenVpartedways The question isn't asking what you're suggesting - at least that's not what I'm reading. My answer isn't intended to be hostile. I'm honestly asking... what is the goal of this question. I'd thought about posting it as a comment but since the end result was "we're not going to answer whether it's been used or how many times if it has", I decided to make it an answer. If the OP wants to rewrite the question in a way that focuses on whether we're going to rework the process, that's a different question.

Comment: I mean, any answer or lack thereof would lead to such speculation

Comment: Feels like what you're getting at is something like: "We can't directly answer this: it's really important to respect privacy if anyone is or has been through any disciplinary procedure (yes, we as a company learned from *big* mistakes here!), and if we answer questions like this, the timing of when the answer changes from 'no' to 'yes' would fuel speculation and rumours. All I will say is: 1) if it hasn't been needed yet, that's a very good thing, 2) if it doesn't perform as hoped, there will be healthy, private discussion with mods to improve it, 3) we will answer questions about the policy"

Comment: You realize that withholding factual information like “We’ve used this process more than once and it worked as intended” because you’re afraid some people might speculate about those facts is the exact opposite of the recently promised transparency, right? Assuming that information is going to be used as fodder for stirring up trouble is not... you know what? Never mind. This is not my problem any longer.

Comment: @ColleenVpartedways I don't think there has been any feedback that SE should make moderator discipline *more public*. Quite the contrary, and I'd be quite upset if part of the process included announcing when the process occurs.

Comment: Mods are elected.  I think the people electing them should be informed when the mod they've chosen is fired.  When that happens, I'd like to think it's _assumed_ that proper process was followed, but it might be good to reassure us of that fact.