# Conduct a [survey] about tags on Meta

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, retag-request

The [survey](/questions/tagged/survey) tag on Meta Stack Exchange is about the Stack Overflow Developer Survey (formerly known as the [Stack Overflow Annual User Survey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158456/stack-overflow-annual-user-survey-2012) and properly under other names as well). Stack *Overflow*, so it's (mostly) off-topic, as stated in the excerpt:

> DO NOT USE this tag unless your question's about the Developer Survey's integration with sites other than Stack Overflow. Most questions about the annual Stack Overflow Developer Survey should be asked on Meta Stack Overflow, not here.

Nowadays, we have more kind of surveys, and users might be tempted to incorrectly apply the [survey](/questions/tagged/survey) tag to their question about them:

- [moderator-engagement-survey](/questions/tagged/moderator-engagement-survey)
- [Site Satisfaction Survey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341721/295232)
- [The Loop Survey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339094/295232) [the-loop](/questions/tagged/the-loop)
- [other kinds of official surveys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306253/295232)

Some of these are on-topic for Meta (or might be in the future).

We could either:

- rename the [survey](/questions/tagged/survey) to [stack-overflow-developer-survey](/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-developer-survey) (this can be done by a ♦ moderator without bumping the 31 questions), and create separate tags for each type of survey
- keep just one [survey](/questions/tagged/survey) tag, adjust the excerpt and wiki, and retag/merge other survey questions into it.

Thoughts?

Comment: On MSO I created a tag [short--survey] as the word *satisfaction* doesn't appear in the topbar notice.

Comment: Won't the first option lead to eventual abuse by people creating the 'survey' tag again?

Comment: @Mast then we burninate it again, no worries.

Comment: Related post from 2018: [Could we change the tag excerpt/wiki and clean up the \[survey\] tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320840/335251)

Answer (score 3):

I'm of the inclination that we should take your first proposed option, and rename this tag.

[This question about The Loop survey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339467/how-were-the-racial-backgrounds-used-by-the-loop-and-previous-surveys-designed) is of rather high traffic despite being incorrectly tagged as [survey](/questions/tagged/survey). While the question *mentions* the 2017 Developer Survey, its focus is not upon it.

In addition, the tag name itself is broad. (I mean, it's called "survey"...) It's definitely a tad confusing at first glance.

A ♦ moderator rename of this tag not bumping the current 34 questions tagged as [survey](/questions/tagged/survey) is just a bonus.

[stack-overflow-developer-survey](/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-developer-survey) seems a fitting enough name.

Comment: I've gone ahead and renamed the [survey] tag to [stack-overflow-developer-survey] now. I've also added [survey] (and some other alternatives) as synonyms of the tag.

Answer (score 3):

I've gone ahead and renamed the [survey](/questions/tagged/survey) tag to [stack-overflow-developer-survey](/questions/tagged/stack-overflow-developer-survey) now, as suggested in [Spevacus' answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341885/335251). I've also added [survey](/questions/tagged/survey) (and some other alternatives) as synonyms of the tag.

Answer (score 1):

I think we should follow your second approach.

There are not too many questions around these topics that warrant a tag for all of them, that's just creating tags for the sake of creating tags.

Besides, the questions regarding the stack-overflow-developer-survey are almost all asked in '13 or earlier. We could even reason to migrate those to MSO, as most of them would be more appropriate over there anyways.

Then all of these other questions could use [survey](/questions/tagged/survey), except question regarding "The Loop", as that already has a dedicated tag [the-loop](/questions/tagged/the-loop).